# Loop from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I'd like a loop that uses a UInt16 (ushort) to loop through all of its values.  However, this doesn't do it:

```
for( ushort i = 0; i < UInt16.MaxValue; i++ )
{
    // do something
}
```

The problem is that the loop will quit when i == 0xFFFF and not "do something".
If I change the 'for' statement to "for(ushort i = 0; i <= UInt16.MaxValue; i++ )", then it becomes an infinite loop because i never gets to 0x10000 because ushorts only go to 0xFFFF.

I could make 'i' an int and cast it or assign it to a ushort variable in the loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have to count up?

Comment: you have the same issue counting down

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `do...while` loop

```
ushort i = 0;
do
{
    // do something
} while(i++ < UInt16.MaxValue);
```

There is an interesting discussion of testing loops at the top vs. the bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/do-your-loops-test-at-the-top-or-bottom).

Comment: Much nicer than my answer. :)

Comment: That's brilliant, yet disturbing somehow ;-)

Comment: extremely disturbing; i'm about to remove my answwer as I made a goof, but counting down would work too, yes? like for(ushort i=UInt16.MaxValue; i>=0; i--)

Comment: Nope, sorry warren. Since i is unsigned, it would never be less than 0. You'd still want a do...while.

Comment: That's why I didn't say "less than" i picked "greater than or equal"

Comment: though you may still be right - I haven't actually tried it, and my brain's about fried on logic and counting right now :P

Comment: warren - if i can't be negative, it will always be greater-than-or-equal-to 0.

Comment: Oddly enough, most of the arithmetic and comparison for ushort is being done with 4 byte ints (take the above code and compile it and load it up in ildasm or reflector)!  Personally, I'd be inclined to use an int as the loop variable for this particular case.

Comment: Normally I would use an int, but there are calls where I need 'i' to be a ushort to call the correct method (overloading).  I'd rather not have to create another variable just for the cast to ushort.

Comment: You don't have to create another variable, just cast it explicitly to ushort.

Comment: It could be a ushort and not be computed with 4-byte ints if it were not a PC architecture. I used to work on an embedded cpu where this question came up every day.

Answer (score 5):

[`UInt16.MaxValue` evaluates to `0xffff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.maxvalue.aspx), not `0x10000`.  I think you can do this with a `do`/`while` loop, as a variation on burkhard1979's answer.

```
ushort i = 0;
do {
   ...
} while (++i != 0);
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. Much more fun!

Comment: The != 0 is redundant. But this method is the sort of thing I use. Integer overflow ftw!

Comment: True.  I'm a little used to C#, which doesn't implicitly convert int to bool like C/C++ does.

Comment: Since it is tagged C# I think it would not work without the !=0

Answer (score 4):

You could simply replace the for by a do-while loop.

```
ushort i = 0;
do
{
i++;
...
} while(i!=UInt16.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be a short?  why not just

```
for(int i = 0;i<=0xFFFF;i++)
{
  //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code suffers from an off by one error (the current code, stops just before having the final value evaluated. Then the following might answer you.

Very simple, as your counter is a 16 bit unsigned integer, it can not have values bigger than `0xffff`, as that value is still valid, you need to have some value that extends beyond that as the guard. However adding `1` to `0xffff` in 16 bits just wraps around to `0`. As suggested, either use a do while loop (that does not need a guard value), or use a larger value to contain your counter.

ps. Using 16 bit variables on modern machines is actually less efficient than using 32 bit variables as no overflow code needs to be generated.