# When is a do-while appropriate?

Tags: language-agnostic, loops

When is a do-while the better choice over other types of loops? What are some common scenarios where its better than others?

I understand the function of a do-while, but not when to use it.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before. Can't find a dupe, though.

Comment: @Hardwareguy Not at all. It just occurred to me while I was working on something that I haven't used it in my entire project.

Comment: Yeah, I find I hardly ever use it.  Even in some cases where I know the loop must be done once before I check the condition, the first iteration is a special case in some way, so it makes more sense to place it outside of the loop block altogether.

Comment: You should clarify it's a loop with test at the end. VB6/VBA has a "Do While ... Loop" syntax that tests at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994905/is-there-ever-a-need-for-a-do-while-loop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390605/while-vs-do-while

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you need something done at least once, but don't know the number of times prior to initiating the loop.

Comment: Couldn't have said it simpler myself. +1

Comment: But there are times when you don't need a do...while to do this, such as something like while(input.hasNext()), so this isn't necessarily a hard rule.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: Well, you can do every kind of loop you need with a simple for statement, so you don't need do/while per se, but I would say that if you want to express intend this is the situation where do/while fits perfectly.

Comment: Does "initiating a loop" mean: 1. initialization of a variable OUTSIDE do ... while statement, or 2. initialization of a variable inside the body of do... while statement?

Answer (score 4):

It's not often that it's the best thing to use, but one scenario is when you must do something at least once, but any further iterations are dependent on some condition.

```
do {
    //do something
} while ( condition );
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually use a do-while when something needs to happen, but it won't necessarily happen "correctly" on the first time. For instance:

```
int x;
do
{
    x = random.next(100);
    cout << x << endl;
} while (x != 13);
```

In this case, the x you start with doesn't matter at all, because it's overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

No-one's yet mentioned its use in C macros...

```
#define do_all(x) do{ foo(x); bar(x); baz(x); } while(0)
```

then in the code you can have

```
do_all(a);
```

- the point being that it gets executed exactly once and the semi-colon on the end of the macro call completes the while(0); statement.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it before if I need to implement lots of conditional checks, for example processing an input form in php.  Probably not the best practice, but it's more readable than many alternatives:

```
do {
   if ( field1_is_invalid ) {
      $err_msg = "field1 is invalid"; break;
   }

   if ( field2_is_invalid ) {
      $err_msg = "field2 is invalid"; break;
   }

   .. check half a dozen more things ..

   // Only executes if all checks succeed.
   do_some_updates();

} while (false)
```

Also, I guess this isn't technically a loop.  More like a way of avoiding using GOTO :)

Comment: Wouldn't just wrapping the same logic in a function and replacing breaks with returns be more readable? You can indicate which check went wrong in your return value too.

Comment: @shylent - yes it would, which is why I mentioned that it probably isn't a best practice.  But it can come in useful from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

It's appropriate when you would like to have your condition checked at the end of the loop execution. Hence the loop will always run at least once and then it will verify if it should iterate further.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you need the user to input some value, the counter variable is based on the input value, you use do-while.
//The following code is in C++. It requires the user to input a number and repeats until users input number larger than 0.

```
do{
    cout << "Enter a Positive integer: ";
    cin >> num;
}while( num < 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

When it is more appropriate to do something and then evaluate the boolean expression...or as Brian said...when you need something done at least once.  This syntax moves the evaluation of the boolean expression to after the loop instead of before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever what is in the loop needs to be executed at least once.

Answer (score 1):

I've long held that do-while is not used in C-based languages as much as it *should* be because the reuse of the "while" keyword is awkward and confusing. Pascal's repeat-until does not share any keywords with its while-begin-end structure.

I'd love to analyze a big heap of code someday and see if do-while is underrepresented in C code compared to similar constructs in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

`do while()` loops while a condition is **true**, but on the other hand, Pascal's `repeat until` loops while a condition is **false** (both will run at least once).

When I program in Pascal I *almost* always use `repeat until`.
When I program in C++ I *almost* always use `while() {}`.
I can't explain why, but I feel it's *normal*. Weird?

Answer (score 1):

when reading from a file or waiting for a connection to be established (other human interaction as well), anything for what the number of iterations is not known a priori (e.g. number of records returned by an sql query), or when you do steps of different size (e.g. read 1 or 5 lines from the file depending on the last one read), when going over all combinations/permutations of objects, whenever 'for' loop conditions become cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

Another exception when you are doing something recursive, like the following with reading inner exceptions:

```
catch(Exception exc)
{
    Exception currentException = exc;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", currentException.GetType().Name, currentException.Message));
    } while((currentException = currentException.InnerException) != null);
}
```