# When are do loops useful?

Tags: php

As you all probably know, `do loops` execute at least once, even if the statement is false — while the `while loop` would never execute even once if the statement is false.

When are do loops useful? Could someone give me a real life example?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1035229/38206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're basically useful when you want something to happen at least once, and maybe more.

The first example that comes to mind is generating a unique ID (non sequentially) in a database.  The approach I sometimes take is:

```
lock table
do {
    id = generate random id
} while(id exists)
insert into db with the generated id
unlock table
```

Basically it will keep generating ids until one doesn't exist (note: potentially an infinite loop, which I might guard against depending on the situation).

Answer (score 0):

The Do loop is very powerfull if you have to check multiple files etc. Due to the guarentee of iteration it will work all the way through.

```
do {
  if($integer > 0) { $nameoffile[0]++; } 
  else { $nameoffile[0] = $nameoffile[0].$integer; }
  $integer++;
} while(file_exists("directory/".$nameoffile[0].".".$nameoffile[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to what has already been answered, you can do crude stuff like this with a do:

```
do
{
    if ($cond1) break;

    if ($cond2) continue;

    do_something();

} while(true/false);
```

Which is a modification of a `switch` loop, which allows continue. You can simulate `goto` similarities in case `goto` is not available and similar.

It must not make your code more readable, so it's often not suggested to do that. But it technically works.