# When should I use do-while instead of while loops?

Tags: c++, coding-style, while-loop, do-while

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there ever a need for a “do {…} while ( )” loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994905/is-there-ever-a-need-for-a-do-while-loop)
>   [Do your loops test at the top or bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/do-your-loops-test-at-the-top-or-bottom)
>   [While vs. Do While](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390605/while-vs-do-while)
>   [When is a do-while appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035229/when-is-a-do-while-appropriate)

I've been having a philosophical debate with a colleague as to whether as a general rule, in C/C++ we should should use while loops rather than do-wile loops.

My feeling is that the *only* time you should use a do-while is if you need to repeatedly test the same thing and you will always want to do so at least once. Generally I always felt that a while loop is more readable.

I realise this could be considered a somewhat subjective / personal style thing, but I'd be interested to hear anyone's thoughts as to whether I'm right or mising something here. Concrete examples would be especially welcome.