# How to nicely output a list of separated strings?

Tags: c++, list, stream

Usually, when I had to display a list of separated strings, I was doing something like:

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> mylist; // Lets consider it has 3 elements : apple, banana and orange.

for (vector<string>::iterator item = mylist.begin(); item != mylist.end(); ++item)
{
  if (item == mylist.begin())
  {
    cout << *item;
  } else
  {
    cout << ", " << *item;
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
apple, banana, orange
```

I recently discovered `std::ostream_iterator` which if found really nice to use.

However with the following code:

```
copy(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
```

If get:

```
apple, banana, orange,
```

Almost perfect, except for the extra `,`. Is there an elegant way to handle the special "first (or last) element case" and to have the same output than the first code, without its "complexity" ?

Comment: Sadly, the answer is no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c) Call me biased if you will (after all, I am), but I think my answer to that question is particularly clean... :-)

Comment: I mean, you can do funky things with `transform` or `accumulate`, but those would involve using functors.  You wouldnt have to write a loop, but you would have to write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although not with std:

```
cout << boost::algorithm::join(mylist, ", ");
```

EDIT: No problem:

```
cout << boost::algorithm::join(mylist | 
    boost::adaptors::transformed(boost::lexical_cast<string,int>), ", "
);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you should indicate that it only works with lists of `string` (or `string`-convertable objects) while `ostream_iterator` can deal with anything `cout` deals with. Upvoted though.