# Best/common practice to delimit values in C when printing them

Tags: c, delimiter, csv

I tried the search function but only found questions regarding *reading* in comma/space delimited files.

My question is however, how do you usually approach this. Say I have a list/array/... of values, like {1, 2, 3, 4} and want to print them with a delimiter.

The simplest version would be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
     unsigned int i;

     for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
     printf("%d, ", list[i]);

     return 0;
}
```

which will obviously print "1, 2, 3, 4, ". The problem I have with that is the comma and space character at the end.

Now I could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", list[i]);
        if (i < 3)
            printf(", ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Bút that doesn't seem like the best way to do it. Can somebody point me into the right direction? Thanks

PS: No, I don't usually hardcode values
PPS: No, I am not trying to write .csv files ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this idiom:

```
assert(n > 0);
printf("%d", list[0]);
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
     printf(", %d", list[i]);
```

Its one disadvantage is that it doesn't scale nicely for n == 0, like a simple loop. Alternatively, you can add protection against n == 0:

```
if (n > 0)
    printf("%d", list[0]);
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
     printf(", %d", list[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very nice and tidy.

Comment: Another disadvantage is that you have to duplicate the body of the loop.

Comment: The `assert(n > 0);` does not look right, that's not a necessary condition to print contents of an array.

Comment: You could quite reasonably replace the `assert()` by `if (n > 0) {` followed by the other code and `}`.

Answer (score 11):

My standard technique for this is:

```
const char *pad = "";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%s%d", pad, list[i]);
    pad = ", ";
}
```

Sometimes, the initial value of pad is a blank, or a colon blank, or whatever else works in context.

Comment: Pretty unusual, I like it. +1

Comment: Unusual indeed, but a very nice idea. But I think I will stick with Michal Trybus version.

Answer (score 3):

I picked up this format with the conditional operator from K&R2:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d%s", list[i], i+1 < n ? ", " : "\n");
```

Comment: @melzer: Yes, the second edition of "The C Programming Language" with the "ANSI C" stamp on the front. I just looked it up: it is used in section 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Well even thought there is already an accepted answer, nobody has come with the obvious one to my taste:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned const n = 4;
    if (n) for (unsigned i = 0; ; ++i) {
        printf("%d", list[i]);
        if (i >= n) break;
        printf(", ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as what the OP mentioned.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I don't know how you measure "pretty much", but the idea is to do just the number of comparisons that are needed, without redundancy. On the other hand it avoids the duplication of the number printing code as in Michał Trybus' solution.

Comment: Oh, good point.  I missed that aspect.  You do have to add an extra check if the list might be empty, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Michal Trybus's version or the reverse

```
for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); ++i) 
{
     printf("%d, ", list[i]);
}
printf("%d", list[n - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( printf("%d",list[i=0]) ; i < n ; printf(", %d", list[++i]) ) ;
```

Comment: I wanted to upvote, because this reminds me of my C lecturer. She loved code nobody can understand. Unfortunately, off-by-one;(

Answer (score 0):

Why not just another version while we're at it.  Here's what I normally do

```
for (i=0;i<n;++i)
{
  if (i) printf(", ");
  printf("%d",list[i]);
}
```