# Is there a simple way to put commas except for the last number in C?

Tags: c

This is a user- defined array and I had a hard time printing the commas and knowing where to stop. This code works but how do i make it simpler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int size;
    int even=0;
    int odd=0;
    int count=0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int array[size];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",array+i);
    }
     for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]%2==0)
        {
            even++;
        }
         if(array[i]%2!=0)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        }
printf("even: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]%2==0)
        {
            printf("%d",array[i]);
            if(count!= even-1)
            {
                printf(", ");
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    count = 0;
    printf("odd: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]%2!=0)
        {
            printf("%d",array[i]);
            if(count!= odd-1)
            {
                printf(", ");
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried dividing the size in to 2 and incrementing it but it only works in smaller arrays. What i did here is that i counted all possible even and odd numbers first before i printed the commas which i think is inefficient.

Comment: One way is to print the separator before each item except the first. Not too different than what you have, but IMO feels cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what a separator is. How do i print a separator?

Comment: A separator is what comes between two items, like a comma and a space,

Comment: A separator is something that separates things, like the comma you're using, or a space, or a tab character. Your code doesn't make much sense - odd or even makes no difference. You know when you're outputting the next to last item, because it will be when `i == size - 1`, and that's the last item you need to print the comma after. Think about that, and you should be able to figure out the code yourself.

Comment: I attempted to use the size-1 approach, but in our assignment, it is required to segregate odd and even numbers. Hence, the last comma in the odd numbers list is not at size-1 index. For example, the even numbers list would be 2, 4, 6, 8, while the odd numbers list would be 1, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: You have two choices, either treat the first element as a special case, or treat the last element as a special case. For this exercise, it's easier to treat the first element as special, since the `count` for the first element will always be 0. When the `count` is 0, just print the element `"%d"`, otherwise print a comma and a space *before* the element `", %d"` By doing it this way, you don't need to know how many even and odd numbers there are.

Comment: @user3386109 There are more than 2 choices as the answer below shows.

Comment: Also see: [Best/common practice to delimit values in C when printing them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3936183/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Is there a simple way to put commas except for the last number in C?*"
The real question is "*how to put a comma **ahead** of every number except the **first** number?*"

You can use the fact that "evens" and "odds" both increment by 2 to your advantage.

The following demonstrates how to use a pointer to the *preamble* separator **ahead** of the next value printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    int size;

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int array[size];

    for( int i = 0 ; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf( "Enter element #%d: ", i+1 );
        scanf( "%d", array+i );
    }

    char *sep = "";
    printf( "even: " );
    for( int i = 0 ; i < size; i += 2 ) { // 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...
        printf( "%s%d", sep, array[i] );
        sep = ", ";
    }
    printf("\n");

    sep = "";
    printf("odd: ");
    for( int i = 1; i < size; i += 2 ) { // 1, 3, 5, 7, 9...
        printf( "%s%d", sep, array[i] );
        sep = ", ";
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Leaving it to you to decide which numbers are "even" and which are "odd" (*natural* numbers vs. *counting* numbers.)

**EDIT**
Of course, the above separates and prints array values at "even and odd" indices... Looking at the OP code a second time, what is wanted is to separate the "even and odd" **values** into two lists. This is a minor change:

```
    char *sep = "";
    printf( "even: " );
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        if( array[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
            printf( "%s%d", sep, array[i] );
            sep = ", ";
        }
    printf("\n");

    sep = "";
    printf("odd: ");
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        if( array[i] % 2 != 0 ) {
            printf( "%s%d", sep, array[i] );
            sep = ", ";
        }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your suggestion for printing commas. As a newbie compsci student trying to code better, you've been a big help! Thanks again!

Comment: @drkcutie If this answer helped you and you think it may help others, "Accepting" the answer will give it (and me) more status.