# What are clever ways to output a list of n items with (n-1) separators inbetween?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, optimization, implementation

Let's say that we have an array with n elements (n > 0).

We would like to output a list of those elements, with a separator between them.

A common approach to this problem is:

```
foreach item
  (
    output item
    output separator
  )
trim last separator
```

But it seems a bit messy to have to do that.

Another approach would be:

```
check that there is at least one element
loop
  (
     output element
     next element, or break if no more elements
     output separator
  )
```

But I am not sure that it will always work.

Do you see other clever ways to do that, for example in C, C++?

Comment: I have not found any duplicate, but there might be. Search terms are not easy to find.

Comment: That’s rather an implementation question than an algorithm question.

Comment: I doubt that anything can beat your second approach.

Comment: wiki as per @benoit's request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
char *sep = "";
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%s%s", sep, item[i]);
    sep = ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) switch(i) {
    default: output_separator();
    case 0: output_item(i);
}
```

or variations on this. I can't really think of how else not to repeat `output_item(i)`.

Comment: Missing a `case` before that `0`

Comment: This looks like it will output 0 and then n-1 separators.

Comment: @Geoffrey - In C, `switch` has implicit fallthrough. You have to specifically `break` to prevent fallthrough.

Comment: Akin too, but less violating than, Duff's device (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).  Paraphrasing, this deserves a vote, but I'm not sure whether up or down (I went with up).

Comment: @lijie - I totally did not just write a generic version of this that takes a pointer to a printing function and a `void *`. And two `size_t`s for the array length and element size.

Comment: @Chris: that would be a totally instructive exercise :)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes:

```
output item 0
for item 1 to n
{
    output separator
    output item
}
```

is shorter.

Answer (score 5):

As it is tagged as language-agnostic I think it's important to point out, that some languages have built-in features to spare you from even thinking about this problem. Take this python code for example:

```
>>> print string.join(['list', 'of', 'some', 'words'], ', ')
list, of, some, words
```

Comment: I think his question is akin to asking how the join-method is implemented.

Comment: @Geoffrey: I disagree, it's language agnostic so the join solution should not only be included but highlighted. I can't tell you how often I see newbies to high level languages try to do the foreach thing without realising that join is the correct way to do this. I used to do it myself.

Comment: Oh by the way, in tcl it would be: `puts [join $list ", "]` and I suppose javascript could be: `console.log(array.join(", "))`

Comment: objective-c: [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "]

Answer (score 5):

A possible C++ solution:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/a746a588cedfa44b

Summary: write an `infix_ostream_iterator`, which is basically the same as `ostream_iterator` except that the "separator" parameter really is a separator, not a suffix to every item. Usage would then be:

```
std::copy(first, last, infix_ostream_iterator<ItemType>(output, separator));
```

Answer (score 5):

For better or worse, I use counted loops, with

```
for (i = 0; i < num_items; i++){
  if (i > 0) output separator;
  output item[i];
}
```

I'm sure this is downvote-bait for being old fashioned, but it works.

If anybody wants to tell me it's inefficient, *boy do I have a flame ready ;-)*

Comment: there is no reason to downvote a working solution. I suppose with iterators it becomes `if(i != mycontainer.begin())`?

Comment: +1.  Absolutely clear.  To whoever downvoted: branch predictors.

Answer (score 3):

This version avoids any additional branches:

```
int i = 0;
goto skip_delim;
do {
               put_delim();
   skip_delim: put_el(i++);
} while (i < size);
```

(For those who are afraid of `goto`, it can be written using approach from Duff's device)

Comment: +2 for mentioning Duff's device, -1 for not actually using switch :)

Comment: @diebuddha the switch have to be outside the loop, not inside like in lijie 's example. If you think it's better than a goto, feel free to use it :) Interesting reading: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

Answer (score 3):

The "first check" idiom in Haskell:

```
intersperse :: Show a => String -> [a] -> String
intersperse _ [] = ""
intersperse s (x:xs) = show x ++ concatMap ((s ++) . show) xs
```

It's used like so:

```
*Main> intersperse "," [1,2,3]
"1,2,3"
*Main> intersperse "," [1]
"1"
*Main> intersperse ";" [1,2]
"1;2"
*Main> intersperse "," []
""
```

Answer (score 2):

I always use first item check idiom. Here is the code in java:

```
List<Object> list;
if (list.size() > 0) {
   put(list.get(0));
}
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
   putSeparator();
   put(list.get(i));                                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in items.length-1; do
   output item; output separator
output last item
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, it's bordering on simple, as long as you can hard-code the separator.

```
(defun return-delimited-list (list &optional stream)
  (format stream "~{~A~^, ~}" list))
```

When called, this returns a string consisting of the elements in `list`, separated by ", " (except for the last element not being followed by anything). Well, if fed an output stream, it prints it to the stream, it just so happens that 'nil' means "No stream, just return a string".