# How to do slicing when using sys.stdout.write()

Tags: python

I have an input like this:

```
country = 'CANADA'
```

and I want the output to be like this:

```
C*A*N*A*D*A
```

I tried to do this:

```
for letter in country:
    tag = letter+'*'
    sys.stdout.write(tag)
```

But I will get `C*A*N*A*D*A*` instead of `C*A*N*A*D*A`. So how do I slice the `sys.stdout.write` or do I have to do other format?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265945/what-are-clever-ways-to-output-a-list-of-n-items-with-n-1-separators-inbetween

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> country = 'CANADA'
>>> '*'.join(country)
'C*A*N*A*D*A'
```

Your version with slicing:

```
>>> country = 'CANADA'
>>> tag = ''
>>> for letter in country:
        tag += letter+'*'


>>> sys.stdout.write(tag[:-1]) # everything up until the last character
C*A*N*A*D*A
```

Comment: Nothing like posting a solution to see literally the exact same solution posted seconds before :p

Comment: @jamylak how to do it with print instead of sys.stdout.write?

Comment: @FynnMahoney `print` is the same except it also adds a new line, so `print tag[:-1]` will print it with a newline after (this is probably desired though). If you don't want the newline use a trailing comma `print tag[:-1],`