# c++ vector to comma delimitated string?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Vector to CSV by adding Comma after each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287329/c-vector-to-csv-by-adding-comma-after-each-element)

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> > recordingArray;
```

I need to convert it to a comma delimitated string so I can store it in a database (is there a better format for the data - it all needs to go in one field)

How can I convert it to a comma delimitated string?

And then later, convert it back?

Comment: I would take a look at boost::algorithm::join and boost::algorithm::split

Comment: Your vector is slightly the same.. the concept is the same either way. It's a duplicate.

Comment: You *could* use the standard library algorithms but I'd prefer to bash it out in a loop. Comma delimiting is as good as any -- provided you remember to escape literal commas, of course.

Comment: Yeah, why would anyone think about reusing code that works and has been tested when they can reinvent all the bugs on their own.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I would suggest that if you can introduce bugs into a simple concatenation loop then programming might not be for you.

Comment: Link to answer using boost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833447/a-good-example-for-boostalgorithmjoin

Answer (score 17):

Use `std::transform` and a `std::stringstream` for this.

```
std::stringstream str;

std::transform(
    recordingArray.begin(),
    recordingArray.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(str, ", "),
    [](const std::pair<int, QString> &p) { return std::to_string(p.first) + ", " + p.second.toStdString(); });
```

Comment: aggregate 'std::stringstream str' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: Did you really downvote me because you don't know how to google std::stringstream and find out which header to include?

Comment: @moswald have an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

```
string line = "";
auto it = recordingArray.begin();

while(it != recordingArray.end())
{
  line.append(*it);
  line.append(',');
}
```

This assumes that each item is directly convertible to a string. You may need to write a toString function.

```
string toString(std::pair<int, QString>> input)
{
  /* convert the data to a string format */
}
```

Then call `line.append(toString(*it))`.

Comment: That will leave a stray `','` on the end.

Comment: Great, thanks very much but it does not name a type? What is 'it'?

Comment: Also, how do I get each part of the vector pair, the int and string?

Comment: He's using C++03, you should put in the actual type instead of `auto`.

Comment: `auto it` expands to `pair<int, QString>::iterator it`. Parts are accessible via `it->first` and `it->second`

Comment: @user1013512: you need to learn C++ before you try to use std::pair.

Comment: I know this post is old, but if you're here like me and you want to leave out the comma at the end then do this: `if(it != --recordingArray.end())`