# Vector to String to Comma String?

Tags: c++

```
QString line = "";
std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> >::iterator it = recordingArray.begin();

while(it != recordingArray.end())
{
  line.append(*it);
  line.append(',');
}
```

The above loops out a vector. I need to convert each part of the pair to a string and then add it into "line".

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you actually want a trailing comma at the end?

Comment: I'd rather not, but it's not that important

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Comment: How is it different? If Qt is an essential ingredient here then you should tag it as such.

Comment: Duplicate of OP's own question from 2 hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809255/c-vector-to-comma-delimitated-string

Comment: Not a duplicate, Im asking a different thing

Comment: @user1013512 No, you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `std::stringstream`, then convert that to a `QString`

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> >::iterator it = recordingArray.begin();

for(; it != recordingArray.end(); ++it)
{
  ss << it->first << ' ' << it->second.toStdString() << ',';
}

QString line = QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
```

EDIT: I'm not sure QString overloads `operator<<(std::ostream &out, const QString &qs)`, so an extra conversion to `std::string` seems necessary.

Comment: aggregate 'std::stringstream ss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: @user1013512 did you `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: Yes, that fixed that, but your code crashes it now at runtime

Comment: @SchighSchagh should `++iter` inside while loop, otherwise infinite loop

Comment: It's the loop causing the freeze

Comment: @billz Aah, good catch. I blindly copied the loop construct from OP's post.