# How to merge the vector_elements of two .csv files in series in one csv file in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

First file, file1.csv

```
4.00
3.00
3.00
4.00
```

Second file, file2.csv

```
10.8
12.4
21.9
17.5
```

I want my final file final.csv in the format

```
4.00 
3.00 
3.00 
4.00 
10.8
12.4
21.9
17.5
```

Comment: `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`, are your friends.

Comment: windows 7 and microsoft visual studio 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear what exactly the part you are stuck on.    Design?   Vector Manipulation?   CSV parsing?   The files don't seem to really be CSV files.   More like flat text files with one value per line?

CSV parsing, the first part, has been answered before.    Here ([How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c))

So, then you have data in vectors.   Combine the two vectors.   That's been answered before as well...  here ([What is the best way to concatenate two vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors)).

Then you need to write out the vector back into CSV.   A simple for loop and printouts should cover that.   However, if you have trouble, its also been answered here ([C++ Vector to CSV by adding Comma after each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287329/c-vector-to-csv-by-adding-comma-after-each-element)).

Good Luck.