# Trimming internal whitespace in std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl, trim

I'm looking for an elegant way to transform an std::string from something like:

```
std::string text = "   a\t   very  \t   ugly   \t\t\t\t   string       ";
```

To:

```
std::string text = "a very ugly string";
```

I've already trimmed the external whitespace with `boost::trim(text);`

[edit]
Thus, multiple whitespaces, and tabs, are reduced to just one space
[/edit]

Removing the external whitespace is trivial. But is there an elegant way of removing the internal whitespace that doesn't involve manual iteration and comparison of previous and next characters? Perhaps something in `boost` I have missed?

Comment: Just a note, I've not really used `boost::split` and `boost::join`, but the obvious way to write this in Python is `' '.join(text.split())`, and something similar should be possible. It's not necessarily as efficient as something that copies the bytes straight to their final location, but it's concise and clear.

Comment: Yeah; split and join work great if you don't mind copying; if you are worried about efficiency (in this case), writing your own loop is probably best.

Comment: @Marshall: I'm working on the basis that the question says, "elegant", not "fast but ugly" ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `std::unique` with `std::remove` along with `::isspace` to compress multiple whitespace characters into single spaces:

```
std::remove(std::unique(std::begin(text), std::end(text), [](char c, char c2) {
    return ::isspace(c) && ::isspace(c2);
}), std::end(text));
```

Comment: It will not solve his problem. `test` also contains `'\t'` which is not equal to `' '`.

Comment: Won't this also do things like "letting" -> "leting" and skip over ` \t` pairs?

Comment: Whoops fixed it again, previously it wouldn't combine, for instance, a space and a tab next to each other, but now it does.

Comment: Doesn't this result in `"a\tvery ugly string"` for the sample input, which is wrong? You could add a pass of `transform` (or maybe a `boost::transform_iterator`?) to replace all whitespace with space characters, but sometimes it's OK to give up and write a loop ;-)

Comment: Why ``std::remove``? You need ``std::replace_if`` after ``std::unique`` to replace ``\t`` characters with ``' '`` and it still wouldn't remove the leading and trailing whitespaces. This answer doesn't do what the OP asked.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::istringstream iss(text);
text = "";
std::string s;
while(iss >> s){
     if ( text != "" ) text += " " + s;
     else text = s;
}
//use text, extra whitespaces are removed from it
```

Comment: Ah, interesting way of doing it, +1, though I've no idea which is more efficient between yours and mine (or that it matters for small strings or "cold" areas of code)

Comment: I think, in the else-block `text.append(" " + s);` would be little bit faster.

Comment: That wouldn't do the same thing would it? (Right now it overwrites what was there before with `operator=` but `append` would be like changing it to `+=`; I think it might be a typo in the original code)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: But that is what we want. Sorry, it was supposed to be `+=`, rather than `+`. I don't know why people voted it when it was not entirely correct :P

Comment: Also a pedantic note, it'd probably be better to do `if (!text.empty())` than `if (text != "")`

Comment: I think you can improve this by doing `iss >> text` right before the `while` loop. This will remove the need for the `if else` block inside it, and you can just have `text += ' ' + s;`

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim_all.hpp>
string s;
boost::algorithm::trim_all(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of what I'd do is similar to what @Nawaz already posted -- read strings from an `istringstream` to get the data without whitespace, and then insert a single space between each of those strings. However, I'd use an `infix_ostream_iterator` from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c/3497021#3497021) to get (IMO) slightly cleaner/clearer code.

```
std::istringstream buffer(input);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(result, " "));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check out https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1808, you'll see a request for (almost) this exact functionality, and a suggested implementation:

```
std::string trim_all ( const std::string &str ) {
return boost::algorithm::find_format_all_copy(
    boost::trim_copy(str),
    boost::algorithm::token_finder (boost::is_space(),boost::algorithm::token_compress_on),
    boost::algorithm::const_formatter(" "));
}
```

Comment: Tried adding a code block but no luck.. adding an answer, but this is the right track I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible version using regular expressions. My GCC 4.6 doesn't have `regex_replace` yet, but Boost.Regex can serve as a drop-in replacement:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// #include <regex>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  using namespace boost;
  string text = "   a\t   very  \t   ugly   \t\t\t\t   string       ";
  trim(text);
  regex pattern{"[[:space:]]+", regex_constants::egrep};
  string result = regex_replace(text, pattern, " ");
  cout << result << endl;
}
```