# How can I get the current position without another variable?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Many times when creating a grammatical list (with comas), I use similar code to the following:

```
std::stringstream list;
int i = 0;
for (auto itemListIt = itemList.begin(); itemListIt != itemList.end(); itemListIt++)
{
    list << *itemListIt;
    if (i < itemList.size() - 1) list << ", ";
    i++;
}
```

Is there some more concise way do this, perhaps without the extra variable - 'i'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not test what you're really interested in; "Is there another element after this one?".

```
std::stringstream list;
for (auto it = roomList.begin(); it != itemList.end(); it++)
{
    list << *it;
    if ( it+1 != itemList.end() ) list << ", ";
}
```

Comment: I though 'it' pointed to the element in the vector. Won't 'it+1' just add 1 to the address?

Comment: Yes, 'it' does point to the element in the vector. but 'it+1' won't add 1 to the address because 'it' is not a C++ pointer. It's an iterator and incrementing an iterator makes it point to the next element. (Not everything that points to something is a regular pointer. Iterators point to things, but they're not normal pointers.)

Comment: Another alternative is to output the comma before each item, except the first which is easy to deduce.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I thought only increment and decrement operators existed for c++ iterators. I guess it depends on the iterator.

Comment: As written, this only works for random access iterators.  In C++11, you can use `std::next( it )` instead of `it + 1`; if you don't have C++11, you've surely got the equivalent in your tool box (but since he's using `auto`, we can safely assume C++11).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz While you can't count on it, it's possible that `it` is a regular pointer.  Most early implementations of `std::vector` defined the iterator as `typedef T* iterator;`, which is a legal, according to the standard.  (Most modern implementations have recognized that this is a bad idea, and do use a class type.)

Comment: The approach with `std::next` will work for forward iterators, but not input iterators. Input iterators are single-pass only, which means you'd have to increment `it` in the loop body *instead* of in the loop continuation condition, not as well as.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It will still work. Since adding one to a `T*` makes it point to the next `T` and vectors are contiguous in memory.

Comment: @SteveJessop `std::next` requires at least a forward iterator.

Comment: @James: exactly, just like `operator+` requires a random access iterator. I'm making basically the same comment you did, but you remarked that Michael's code requires RandomAccessIterator, and I'm remarking that your code requires ForwardIterator. It's probably safe to assume that something called `itemList.begin()` returns at least a forward iterator, but the questioner has a known habit of naming a stream `list`, so I'm playing safe ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Playing safe probably doesn't hurt.  In practice, I'll generally use the second form in my own answer, which avoids the problem.  (Both of my solutions do work with input iterators.)

Comment: In the pseudo-code I'm using auto because it's cool, not because my compiler supports it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple solutions for this.  The first is to use a `while`
loop:

```
auto itemListIt = itemList.begin();
while ( itemListIt != itemList.end() ) {
    list << *itemListIt;
    ++ itemListIt;
    if ( itemListIt != itemList.end() ) {
        list << ", ";
    }
}
```

The second solution is to change the logic slightly: instead of 
appending a `", "` if there is more to follow, prefix one if you're not
the first element:

```
for ( auto itemListIt = itemList.begin(); itemListIt != itemList.end(); ++ itemListIt ) {
    if ( itemListIt != itemList.begin() ) {
        list << ", ";
    }
    list << *itemListIt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over everything up to the next to last using `--items.end()`.

Then output the last one using `items.back()`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    std::vector<int> items;
    items.push_back(1);
    items.push_back(1);
    items.push_back(2);
    items.push_back(3);
    items.push_back(5);
    items.push_back(8);

    if(items.size() > 1)
    {
        std::copy(items.begin(), --items.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ", "));
        oss << "and ";
    }
    // else do nothing

    oss << items.back();

    std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

Output:

`1, 1, 2, 3, 5, and 8`

Comment: I don't think that post-decrementing the result of `items.end()` does what you think anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop Updated and to pre-increment and [tested](http://ideone.com/5Yy3H), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with any `InputIterator` input:

```
std::stringstream list;
auto it(std::begin(input)); //Or however you get the input
auto end(std::end(input));
bool first(true);
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    if (!first) list << ", ";
    else first = false;
    list << *it;
}
```

Or without an extra variable:

```
std::stringstream list;
auto it(std::begin(input)); //Or however you get the input
auto end(std::end(input));
if (it != end)
{
    list << *it;
    ++it;
}
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
    list << ", " << *it;
}
```

Comment: It still has an extra the variable - first

Comment: @doobie: Yeah, I guess this doesn't really answer the question. That said, it is not possible to do this _without_ an extra variable or duplicate code (for input iterators). I've added the "duplicate code" version.

Comment: @doobie: Ugh, I am stupid :$. James Kanze's answer is also a valid way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do that with a map or other iterators that cannot do random access, as others have suggested, check for the first element:

```
std::stringstream query;
query << "select id from dueShipments where package in (";
for (auto it = packageList.begin(); it != packageList.end(); it++)
{
    if (it != packageList.begin()) query << ", ";
    query << it->second;
}
query << ")";
```