# Don't print trailing delimiter stream_iterator C++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, ostream

What is the most elegant way, in your opinion, to print to `std::cout` using `std::ostream_iterator` in C++11 and avoid printing a trailing delimeter?

The object I'm printing has bidirectional iterators, but not random access iterators.

```
std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::copy(x.begin(), std::prev(x.end()),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",") );
if ( x.size() != 0 )
  std::cout << *(--x.end()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: "*Most elegant*" is subjective by definition (read: not constructive).

Comment: @ildjarn I've edited to read "in your opinion", but I feel you're comment is a little pedantic: Do you really not think this is a useful question? I would have written "most concise" instead of "most elegant", but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity is not computable. ; )

Comment: There is no elegant way to do this. You have to make a check for some special case. Hide it in a function and move on.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Even if there is no one-liner, is the way I've written really what you would do? If so, that's enough for me.

Comment: If you already have a container, you could try the [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

Comment: You should look at [infix_iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3497021/906773).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one of my favorites, but it doesn't use `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iosfwd>

template <class C>
auto
print(std::ostream& os, const C& c,
      const std::string& delim = std::string(", "),
      const std::string& open_brace = std::string("{"),
      const std::string& close_brace = std::string("}")
     ) -> decltype(std::begin(c), std::end(c), os)
{
    os << open_brace;
    auto i = std::begin(c);
    auto e = std::end(c);
    if (i != e)
    {
        os << *i;
        for (++i; i != e; ++i)
            os << delim << *i;
    }
    os << close_brace;
    return os;
}

#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    print(std::cout, x) << '\n';
}

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

**Update**

Oliver goaded me into a challenge I couldn't resist. :-)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iosfwd>

namespace my {

template <class C>
auto
print(std::ostream& os, const C& c,
      const std::string& delim = std::string(", "),
      const std::string& open_brace = std::string("{"),
      const std::string& close_brace = std::string("}")
     ) -> decltype(std::begin(c), std::end(c), os);

template <class C,
           typename std::enable_if
                    <
                       !std::is_same<C, std::string>::value,
                    bool>::type = false
         >
inline
auto
operator<< (std::ostream& os, const C& c) -> decltype(print(os, c))
{
    return print(os, c);
}

template <class C>
auto
print(std::ostream& os, const C& c,
      const std::string& delim,
      const std::string& open_brace,
      const std::string& close_brace
     ) -> decltype(std::begin(c), std::end(c), os)
{
    os << open_brace;
    auto i = std::begin(c);
    auto e = std::end(c);
    if (i != e)
    {
        os << *i;
        for (++i; i != e; ++i)
            os << delim << *i;
    }
    os << close_brace;
    return os;
}

}

#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<std::list<double>> x{{}, {3, 2, 1}, {1,2,3,4,5,6}};
    my::print(std::cout, x) << '\n';
}

{{}, {3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
```

It isn't perfect, but it was fun. :-)  There's probably a better way to do it that would propagate the custom delimiter and braces more faithfully.

Comment: +1 Is there a tweak to this so that it can print `list<list<double> >`? Maybe recursively calling print on the inner objects if they're containers?

Comment: May I ask why is that `decltype(std::begin(c), std::end(c), os)` for? Couldn't the return value just be `std::ostream&`?

Comment: @Oliver:  Yes, recursively calling print on the inner objects is probably the way to go.  I slapped together an alternative just for fun.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Super cool! This is going to be great for debugging (I always talk myself into just typing out the nested for loops "just this once". : )

Comment: @mfontanini:  I wanted to restrict the `print<C>` function to just those types where `std::begin(c)` and `std::end(c)` are legal.  This would enable me to later (for example) create a `print(std::ostream&, double)` overload and not have to worry that calls to this new overload would get mistakenly routed to the container version of `print(std::ostream&, const C&)`.  I.e. if the `decltype` in the trailing return isn't valid for a specific instantiation of `C`, then that instantiation is SFINAE'd out.

Answer (score 3):

Simply move back your cursor by:

```
std::cout << "\b";
```

and then overwrite the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

C++14 - unfortunately requires in/out stream:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<double> x{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::stringstream sstr;
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(sstr), [&](auto c){
        return (sstr.rdbuf()->in_avail() ? "," : "") + std::to_string(c);
    });
    std::cout << sstr.str() << std::endl;
}
```

[live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dF8axEqC9sDZI0do)

Since C++17 there will be [ostream_joiner](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) which will fix this problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int i[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::copy(std::begin(i),
              std::end(i),
              std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

[live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DRX6WPBghH2bmv3A)