# Print vector/collection values joined with ", "

Tags: c++, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing lists with commas C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Is there a nice way to print the elements of a vector joined with ", "? I am hoping for a simple and clean one-liner, or similar. A quality which I would not attribute to the version I came up so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13};

  if (v.size() > 1) {
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
  }

  if (v.size() > 0) {
    std::cout << *(v.end() - 1) << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13
```

Comment: What's the question? What didn't work for you?

Comment: You really wouldn't consider that a clean one-liner?

Comment: Your code as is doesn't work quite right. Note that the 8 isn't printed. Change the `v.end()-2` to `v.end()-1`.

Comment: @Xymostech: No, it's a clean four-liner (although not quite clean enough to make off-by-one errors obvious).

Comment: This isn't a one-liner, so I'm not offering as a solution: You only need one if test, the one for `size()>0`. Change the `v.end()-2` to `v.end()-1` and there's no need for that test for `size()>1`.