# Converting a hex string to a byte array

Tags: c++, string, hex

What is the best way to convert a variable length hex string e.g. `"01A1"` to a byte array containing that data.

i.e converting this:

```
std::string = "01A1";
```

into this

```
char* hexArray;
int hexLength;
```

or this

```
std::vector<char> hexArray;
```

so that when I write this to a file and `hexdump -C` it I get the binary data containing `01A1`.

Comment: @alexvii That is not an answer to this question.

Comment: You can set std::streams to hex mode for reading and writing numbers in hex format

Comment: @makulik I did try using streams and std::hex but couldn't get anything to work. Could you maybe show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think any ascii deduction is required, simply use the c api to convert into char array, unless i have gotten question wrong. I have pointed out the api in my ans below http://stackoverflow.com/a/17273020/986760.

Comment: Based on a comment you made to another answer I think you need to add to your question what should happen when the input is an odd number of characters. Should the missing 0 be added to the beginning of the string or the end?

Comment: @oracal See my answer for a stringstream approach

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
int char2int(char input)
{
  if(input >= '0' && input <= '9')
    return input - '0';
  if(input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
    return input - 'A' + 10;
  if(input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
    return input - 'a' + 10;
  throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid input string");
}

// This function assumes src to be a zero terminated sanitized string with
// an even number of [0-9a-f] characters, and target to be sufficiently large
void hex2bin(const char* src, char* target)
{
  while(*src && src[1])
  {
    *(target++) = char2int(*src)*16 + char2int(src[1]);
    src += 2;
  }
}
```

Depending on your specific platform there's probably also a standard implementation though.

Comment: While that does seem to work (can't try it out atm) is there a more standard way?

Comment: I am not sure, the original string has the same elements, why do we need to covert to ascii to get numerical equivalent?

Comment: @fayyazkl I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes What is wrong with using c_str() for the above? Why do we have to manually convert an ascii 'A' to hex A and put in target char *. What you did is correct. I just can't see why you have to manually do it when there is standard api available to covert string to char array.

Comment: @fayyazkl you misunderstood the question - this is about converting the human-readable 4-character string `"01A1"` into 2 in memory bytes (1 and 161). Hence ASCII conversion is obviously required.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes wonderfull solution ! But what happens if there is an odd number of hex digits.  For example AFF ?

Comment: @Christophe because the `while` checks for `*src && src[1]` it would parse `AF` and then encounter a trailing zero on `src[1]`, and stop converting. It's similar to `atoi` behaviour in that respect - it stops on corrupt input.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I'm not sure that atoi() ignores the last odd digit...  Don't you think that it looks a little bit like a bug when AFF is handled as AF instead of 0AFF ?

Comment: @Christophe I was referring to `atoi` behaviour of parsing 'as long as it has meaningful input' - if you feed it the string `123abc` it returns integer `123` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/). As such I wrote this function on the same premise of sanitized input, and 'undefined or messy' behaviour otherwise. Adding input validation is rather trivial of course anyway, but not always a wanted overhead.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I know I am replying to an answer that was posted years ago, but I just want to say thanks for the solution! This is exactly what I needed, I was using another way I found online but it had a few problems and it didn't work exactly like it should have been. So thanks again! :)

Comment: Love this solution. As a minor observation, do note that char2input can be made slightly more efficient, especially if used heavily. Note that any valid character will be >= '0' so it is more efficient to test for the second character first, as in:

int char2int(char input)
   {
   if (input <= '9' && input >= '0')
     return input - '0';
   if (input <= 'F' && input >= 'A')
     return input - 'A' + 10;
   if (input <= 'f' && input >= 'a')
     return input - 'a' + 10;
   }
Or test for a, then A and then 0, in that order.

Answer (score 49):

This implementation uses the built-in [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function to handle the actual conversion from text to bytes, but will work for any even-length hex string.

```
std::vector<char> HexToBytes(const std::string& hex) {
  std::vector<char> bytes;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
    std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
    char byte = (char) strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    bytes.push_back(byte);
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: well you can always pre-append '0' to for odd sized hex string

Answer (score 15):

You can use boost:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

char bytes[60] = {0}; 
std::string hash = boost::algorithm::unhex(std::string("313233343536373839")); 
std::copy(hash.begin(), hash.end(), bytes);
```

Answer (score 11):

So for fun, I was curious if I could do this kind of conversion at compile-time.  It doesn't have a lot of error checking and was done in VS2015, which doesn't support C++14 constexpr functions yet (thus how HexCharToInt looks).  It takes a c-string array, converts pairs of characters into a single byte and expands those bytes into a uniform initialization list used to initialize the T type provided as a template parameter.  T could be replaced with something like std::array to automatically return an array.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

/* Quick and dirty conversion from a single character to its hex equivelent */
constexpr std::uint8_t HexCharToInt(char Input)
{
    return
    ((Input >= 'a') && (Input <= 'f'))
    ? (Input - 87)
    : ((Input >= 'A') && (Input <= 'F'))
    ? (Input - 55)
    : ((Input >= '0') && (Input <= '9'))
    ? (Input - 48)
    : throw std::exception{};
}

/* Position the characters into the appropriate nibble */
constexpr std::uint8_t HexChar(char High, char Low)
{
    return (HexCharToInt(High) << 4) | (HexCharToInt(Low));
}

/* Adapter that performs sets of 2 characters into a single byte and combine the results into a uniform initialization list used to initialize T */
template <typename T, std::size_t Length, std::size_t ... Index>
constexpr T HexString(const char (&Input)[Length], const std::index_sequence<Index...>&)
{
    return T{HexChar(Input[(Index * 2)], Input[((Index * 2) + 1)])...};
}

/* Entry function */
template <typename T, std::size_t Length>
constexpr T HexString(const char (&Input)[Length])
{
    return HexString<T>(Input, std::make_index_sequence<(Length / 2)>{});
}

constexpr auto Y = KS::Utility::HexString<std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>>("ABCDEF");
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I wanted a way of initializing an array from a string literal, and this is almost exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

You said "variable length." Just how variable do you mean?

For hex strings that fit into an unsigned long I have always liked the C function `strtoul`. To make it convert hex pass 16 as the radix value.

Code might look like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
std::string str = "01a1";
unsigned long val = strtoul(str.c_str(), 0, 16);
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with a `stringstream`, you just need to store the value in an intermediate numeric type such as an `int`:

```
  std::string test = "01A1"; // assuming this is an even length string
  char bytes[test.length()/2];
  stringstream converter;
  for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i+=2)
  {
      converter << std::hex << test.substr(i,2);
      int byte;
      converter >> byte;
      bytes[i/2] = byte & 0xFF;
      converter.str(std::string());
      converter.clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use OpenSSL to do it, there is a nifty trick I found:

```
BIGNUM *input = BN_new();
int input_length = BN_hex2bn(&input, argv[2]);
input_length = (input_length + 1) / 2; // BN_hex2bn() returns number of hex digits
unsigned char *input_buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(input_length);
retval = BN_bn2bin(input, input_buffer);
```

Just be sure to strip off any leading '0x' to the string.

Comment: Be sure to BN_free

Answer (score 3):

Somebody mentioned using sscanf to do this, but didn't say how. This is how. It's useful because it also works in ancient versions of C and C++ and even most versions of embedded C or C++ for microcontrollers.

When converted to bytes, the hex-string in this example resolves to the ASCII text "Hello there!" which is then printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char hexdata[] = "48656c6c6f20746865726521";
    char bytedata[20]{};
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(hexdata) / 2; j++) {
        sscanf(hexdata + j * 2, "%02hhX", bytedata + j);
    }
    printf ("%s -> %s\n", hexdata, bytedata);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a standard function like `sscanf` to read the string into an unsigned integer, and then you already have the bytes you need in memory. If you were on a big endian machine you could just write out (`memcpy`) the memory of the integer from the first non-zero byte. However you can't safely assume this in general, so you can use some bit masking and shifting to get the bytes out.

```
const char* src = "01A1";
char hexArray[256] = {0};
int hexLength = 0;

// read in the string
unsigned int hex = 0;
sscanf(src, "%x", &hex);

// write it out
for (unsigned int mask = 0xff000000, bitPos=24; mask; mask>>=8, bitPos-=8) {
    unsigned int currByte = hex & mask;
    if (currByte || hexLength) {
        hexArray[hexLength++] = currByte>>bitPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++11 variant (with gcc 4.7 - little endian format):

```
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    std::vector<uint8_t> decodeHex(const std::string & source)
    {
        if ( std::string::npos != source.find_first_not_of("0123456789ABCDEFabcdef") )
        {
            // you can throw exception here
            return {};
        }

        union
        {
            uint64_t binary;
            char byte[8];
        } value{};

        auto size = source.size(), offset = (size % 16);
        std::vector<uint8_t> binary{};
        binary.reserve((size + 1) / 2);

        if ( offset )
        {
            value.binary = std::stoull(source.substr(0, offset), nullptr, 16);

            for ( auto index = (offset + 1) / 2; index--; )
            {
                binary.emplace_back(value.byte[index]);
            }
        }

        for ( ; offset < size; offset += 16 )
        {
            value.binary = std::stoull(source.substr(offset, 16), nullptr, 16);
            for ( auto index = 8; index--; )
            {
                binary.emplace_back(value.byte[index]);
            }
        }

        return binary;
    }
```

Crypto++ variant (with gcc 4.7):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <crypto++/filters.h>
#include <crypto++/hex.h>

std::vector<unsigned char> decodeHex(const std::string & source)
{
    std::string hexCode;
    CryptoPP::StringSource(
              source, true,
              new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hexCode)));

    return std::vector<unsigned char>(hexCode.begin(), hexCode.end());
}
```

Note that the first variant is about two times faster than the second one and at the same time works with odd and even number of nibbles (the result of "a56ac" is {0x0a, 0x56, 0xac}). Crypto++ discards the last one if there are odd number of nibbels (the result of "a56ac" is {0xa5, 0x6a}) and silently skips invalid hex characters (the result of "a5sac" is {0xa5, 0xac}).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s("313233");
    char delim = ',';
    int len = s.size();
    for(int i = 2; i < len; i += 3, ++len) s.insert(i, 1, delim);
    std::istringstream is(s);
    std::ostringstream os;
    is >> std::hex;
    int n;
    while (is >> n) {
        char c = (char)n;
        os << std::string(&c, 1);
        if(is.peek() == delim) is.ignore();
    }

    // std::string form
    std::string byte_string = os.str();
    std::cout << byte_string << std::endl;
    printf("%s\n", byte_string.c_str());

    // std::vector form
    std::vector<char> byte_vector(byte_string.begin(), byte_string.end());
    byte_vector.push_back('\0'); // needed for a c-string
    printf("%s\n", byte_vector.data());
}
```

The output is

```
123
123
123
```

'1' == 0x31, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is speed, I have an AVX2 SIMD implementation of an encoder and decoder here: https://github.com/zbjornson/fast-hex. These benchmark ~12x faster than the fastest scalar implementations.

Comment: does it flag invalid input?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using byte = unsigned char;

static int charToInt(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    return -1;
}

// Decodes specified HEX string to bytes array. Specified nBytes is length of bytes
// array. Returns -1 if fails to decode any of bytes. Returns number of bytes decoded
// on success. Maximum number of bytes decoded will be equal to nBytes. It is assumed
// that specified string is '\0' terminated.
int hexStringToBytes(const char* str, byte* bytes, int nBytes) {
    int nDecoded {0};
    for (int i {0}; str[i] != '\0' && nDecoded < nBytes; i += 2, nDecoded += 1) {
        if (str[i + 1] != '\0') {
            int m {charToInt(str[i])};
            int n {charToInt(str[i + 1])};
            if (m != -1 && n != -1) {
                bytes[nDecoded] = (m << 4) | n;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return nDecoded;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    byte bytes[0x100];
    int ret {hexStringToBytes(argv[1], bytes, 0x100)};
    if (ret < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "number of bytes: " << ret << "\n" << std::hex;
    for (int i {0}; i < ret; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i] < 0x10) {
            std::cout << "0";
        }
        std::cout << (bytes[i] & 0xff);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i've modified TheoretiCAL's code

```
uint8_t buf[32] = {};
std::string hex = "0123";
while (hex.length() % 2)
    hex = "0" + hex;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << hex;

for (size_t i= 0; i <sizeof(buf); i++)
    stream >> buf[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

How I do this at compiletime

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

#define DELIMITING_WILDCARD ' '

//  @sean :)
constexpr int _char_to_int( char ch )
{
    if( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
        return ch - '0';

    if( ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F' )
        return ch - 'A' + 10;

    return ch - 'a' + 10;
};

template <char wildcard, typename T, size_t N = sizeof( T )>
constexpr size_t _count_wildcard( T &&str )
{
    size_t count = 1u;
    for( const auto &character : str )
    {
        if( character == wildcard )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

//  construct a base16 hex and emplace it at make_count
//  change 16 to 256 if u want the result to be when:
//  sig[0] == 0xA && sig[1] == 0xB = 0xA0B
//  or leave as is for the scenario to return 0xAB
#define CONCATE_HEX_FACTOR 16
#define CONCATE_HEX(a, b) ( CONCATE_HEX_FACTOR * ( a ) + ( b ) )

template
<   char skip_wildcard,
    //  How many occurances of a delimiting wildcard do we find in sig
    size_t delimiter_count,
    typename T, size_t N = sizeof( T )>
    constexpr auto _make_array( T &&sig )
{
    static_assert( delimiter_count > 0, "this is a logical error, delimiter count can't be of size 0" );
    static_assert( N > 1, "sig length must be bigger than 1" );

    //  Resulting byte array, for delimiter_count skips we should have delimiter_count integers
    std::array<int, delimiter_count> ret{};

    //  List of skips that point to the position of the delimiter wildcard in skip
    std::array<size_t, delimiter_count> skips{};

    //  Current skip
    size_t skip_count = 0u;

    //  Character count, traversed for skip
    size_t skip_traversed_character_count = 0u;
    for( size_t i = 0u; i < N; ++i )
    {
        if( sig[i] == DELIMITING_WILDCARD )
        {
            skips[skip_count] = skip_traversed_character_count;
            ++skip_count;
        }

        ++skip_traversed_character_count;
    }

    //  Finally traversed character count
    size_t traversed_character_count = 0u;

    //  Make count (we will supposedly have at least an instance in our return array)
    size_t make_count = 1u;

    //  Traverse signature
    for( size_t i = 0u; i < N; ++i )
    {
        //  Read before
        if( i == 0u )
        {
            //  We don't care about this, and we don't want to use 0
            if( sig[0u] == skip_wildcard )
            {
                ret[0u] = -1;
                continue;
            }

            ret[0u] = CONCATE_HEX( _char_to_int( sig[0u] ), _char_to_int( sig[1u] ) );
            continue;
        }

        //  Make result by skip data
        for( const auto &skip : skips )
        {
            if( ( skip == i ) && skip < N - 1u )
            {
                //  We don't care about this, and we don't want to use 0
                if( sig[i + 1u] == skip_wildcard )
                {
                    ret[make_count] = -1;
                    ++make_count;
                    continue;
                }

                ret[make_count] = CONCATE_HEX( _char_to_int( sig[i + 1u] ), _char_to_int( sig[i + 2u] ) );
                ++make_count;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

#define SKIP_WILDCARD '?'
#define BUILD_ARRAY(a) _make_array<SKIP_WILDCARD, _count_wildcard<DELIMITING_WILDCARD>( a )>( a )
#define BUILD_ARRAY_MV(a) _make_array<SKIP_WILDCARD, _count_wildcard<DELIMITING_WILDCARD>( std::move( a ) )>( std::move( a ) )

//  -----
//  usage
//  -----
template <int n>
constexpr int combine_two()
{
    constexpr auto numbers = BUILD_ARRAY( "55 8B EC 83 E4 F8 8B 4D 08 BA ? ? ? ? E8 ? ? ? ? 85 C0 75 12 ?" );
    constexpr int number = numbers[0];
    constexpr int number_now = n + number;
    return number_now;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto shit = BUILD_ARRAY( "?? AA BB CC DD ? ? ? 02 31 32" );
    for( const auto &hex : shit )
    {
        printf( "%x ", hex );
    }

    combine_two<3>();
    constexpr auto saaahhah = combine_two<3>();
    static_assert( combine_two<3>() == 88 );
    static_assert( combine_two<3>() == saaahhah );
    printf( "\n%d", saaahhah );
}
```

Method can be used for runtime too, but for that you'd probably prefer something else, faster.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to someone. The logic of translating a set of bytes into a string and back. Solves the zero character problem.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string BytesToHex(const std::vector<char>& data, size_t len)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

    for(size_t index(0); index < len; ++index)
    {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned short>(data[index]);
    }

    return ss.str();
}

std::vector<char> HexToBytes(const std::string& data)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << data;

    std::vector<char> resBytes;
    size_t count = 0;
    const auto len = data.size();
    while(ss.good() && count < len)
    {
        unsigned short num;
        char hexNum[2];
        ss.read(hexNum, 2);
        sscanf(hexNum, "%2hX", &num);
        resBytes.push_back(static_cast<char>(num));
        count += 2;
    }
    return resBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++23 solution. You could literally turn it into a `std::vector<std::byte> vec(...);` one-liner if you wanted to.

```cpp
std::string_view in("09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36");

auto view = in
    | std::views::transform([](char c) {
        // map ASCII characters onto hex digit numeric values
        // (doesn't work correctly if c isn't a hex digit)
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c - '0' : 10 + c - 'a';
    })
    | std::views::adjacent_transform<2>([](unsigned char hi, unsigned char lo) {
        return std::byte(hi << 4 | lo);
    });

// note: you might not even need the vector and could work with the view directly

// create a vector containing all the elements in the view
std::vector<std::byte> bytes(std::from_range, view);

// if std::from_range is not support yet:
std::vector<std::byte> bytes(view.begin(), view.end());
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7MsvbWTMz)*.

Note that `char` makes for a bad "byte" type; you should be using `std::byte` for this purpose whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your data to look like this e.g array of "0x01", "0xA1"
Then you can iterate your array and use sscanf to create the array of values

```
unsigned int result;
sscanf(data, "%x", &result);
```

Comment: Is this a "hint" or an answer? And what do you mean by "try this"? Will it work? And is it different from the existing answers? How?

Comment: @jogojapan I am happy write the whole code do you really need it ?
Can you see the difference in basic approach?

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand what you are trying to tell us. There is a hint, there is a string (followed by another version of that string with `0x` prefixed), and then a very short statement about some iteration. The meaning of all this, esp. in the context of the existing answers, isn't clear to me. This will have an impact on upvotes/downvotes you'll get for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question, but the accepted answer didn't look like a C++ way of solving the task to me (this doesn't mean it's a bad answer or anything, just explaining motivation behind adding this one). I recollected [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3497021/1535516) and decided to implement something similar. Here is complete code of what I ended up with (it also works for `std::wstring`):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename OutputIt>
class hex_ostream_iterator :
    public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
    OutputIt out;
    int digitCount;
    int number;

public:
    hex_ostream_iterator(OutputIt out) : out(out), digitCount(0), number(0)
    {
    }

    hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt> &
    operator=(char c)
    {
        number = (number << 4) | char2int(c);
        digitCount++;

        if (digitCount == 2) {
            digitCount = 0;
            *out++ = number;
            number = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt> &
    operator*()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt> &
    operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt> &
    operator++(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int
    char2int(char c)
    {
        static const std::string HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef";

        const char lowerC = std::tolower(c);
        const std::string::size_type pos = HEX_CHARS.find_first_of(lowerC);
        if (pos == std::string::npos) {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Not a hex digit: ") + c);
        }
        return pos;
    }
};

template <typename OutputIt>
hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt>
hex_iterator(OutputIt out)
{
    return hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt>(out);
}

template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
hex_ostream_iterator<OutputIt>
from_hex_string(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt out)
{
    if (std::distance(first, last) % 2 == 1) {
        *out = '0';
        ++out;
    }
    return std::copy(first, last, out);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " hexstring" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::string input = argv[1];
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    from_hex_string(input.begin(), input.end(),
                    hex_iterator(std::back_inserter(bytes)));

    typedef std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char> osit;
    std::copy(bytes.begin(), bytes.end(), osit(std::cout));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the output of `./hex2bytes 61a062a063 | hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  61 a0 62 a0 63                                    |a.b.c|
00000005
```

And of `./hex2bytes 6a062a063 | hexdump -C` (note odd number of characters):

```
00000000  06 a0 62 a0 63                                    |..b.c|
00000005
```

Comment: very nice char2int() !  But I fear that the result doesn't meet expectations when with odd number of hex digits.  For example, try with 6a062a063.   I'd understand 6 a0 62 a0 63, but your code makes 6a 06 2a 06 3 out of it.

Comment: You're right about odd number of hex digits, @Christophe. Thank you! I updated the code to handle such case well (by the way, it's not true for the accepted answer, still better to handle such strings).

Comment: It should be noted that I wrote the accepted answer as the most performant full solution to the OP's question  :)   No questions were asked about exceptional cases, so I assumed (like many stdc functions do) pre-sanitized input.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in an hex to char conversion is that the hex digits work pairwise, f.ex: 3132 or A0FF. So an even number of hex digits is assumed.  However it could be perfectly valid to have an odd number of digits, like: 332 and AFF, which should be understood as 0332 and 0AFF.

I propose an improvement to Niels Keurentjes hex2bin() function. 
First we count the number of valid hex digits. As we have to count, let's control also the buffer size:

```
void hex2bin(const char* src, char* target, size_t size_target)
{
    int countdgts=0;    // count hex digits
    for (const char *p=src; *p && isxdigit(*p); p++) 
        countdgts++;                            
    if ((countdgts+1)/2+1>size_target)
        throw exception("Risk of buffer overflow");
```

By the way, to use `isxdigit()` you'll have to `#include <cctype>`.
Once we know how many digits, we can determine if the first one is the higher digit (only pairs) or not (first digit not a pair).

```
bool ishi = !(countdgts%2);
```

Then we can loop digit by digit, combining each pair using bin shift << and bin or, and 
toggling the 'high' indicator at each iteration:

```
    for (*target=0; *src; ishi = !ishi)  {    
        char tmp = char2int(*src++);    // hex digit on 4 lower bits
        if (ishi)
            *target = (tmp << 4);   // high:  shift by 4
        else *target++ |= tmp;      // low:  complete previous  
    } 
  *target=0;    // null terminated target (if desired)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In: "303132", Out: "012". Input string can be odd or even length.

```
char char2int(char input)
{
    if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        return input - '0';
    if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
        return input - 'A' + 10;
    if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
        return input - 'a' + 10;

    throw std::runtime_error("Incorrect symbol in hex string");
};

string hex2str(string &hex)
{
    string out;
    out.resize(hex.size() / 2 + hex.size() % 2);

    string::iterator it = hex.begin();
    string::iterator out_it = out.begin();
    if (hex.size() % 2 != 0) {
        *out_it++ = char(char2int(*it++));
    }

    for (; it < hex.end() - 1; it++) {
        *out_it++ = char2int(*it++) << 4 | char2int(*it);
    };

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to some of the other answers here, this is what I went with:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

BYTE* ByteUtils::HexStringToBytes(BYTE* HexString, int ArrayLength)
{
  BYTE* returnBytes;
  returnBytes = (BYTE*) malloc(ArrayLength/2);
  int j=0;

  for(int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++)
  {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
      int valueHigh = (int)(*(HexString+i));
      int valueLow =  (int)(*(HexString+i+1));

      valueHigh = ByteUtils::HexAsciiToDec(valueHigh);
      valueLow =  ByteUtils::HexAsciiToDec(valueLow);

      valueHigh *= 16;
      int total = valueHigh + valueLow;
      *(returnBytes+j++) = (BYTE)total;
    }
  }
  return returnBytes;
}

int ByteUtils::HexAsciiToDec(int value)
{
  if(value > 47 && value < 59)
  {
    value -= 48;
  }
  else if(value > 96 && value < 103)
  {
    value -= 97;
    value += 10;
  }
  else if(value > 64 && value < 71)
  {
    value -= 65;
    value += 10;
  }
  else
  {
    value = 0;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool Hexadec2xdigit(const std::string& data, std::string& buffer, std::size_t offset = sizeof(uint16_t))
{
    if (data.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        constexpr auto s_function_lambda = [] (const char* string) noexcept { return *static_cast<const uint16_t*>(reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(string)); };
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0, tmp = s_function_lambda(data.c_str() + i); i < data.size(); i += offset, tmp = s_function_lambda(data.c_str() + i))
            {
                if (std::isxdigit(data[i]))
                {
                    buffer += static_cast<char>(/*std::stoul*/std::strtoul(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(std::addressof(tmp)), NULL, 16));
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& ex)
    {

    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range& ex)
    {

    }

    return false;
}
```

- This code doesn't have much of a copy process