# converting a string array to byte array in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string say :

```
string abc = "1023456789ABCD"
```

I want to convert it into a byte array like :

```
byte[0] = 0x10;
byte[1] = 0x23;
byte[2] = 0x45; 
----
```

and so on

I checked some of the posts here but couldn't find the proper solution.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a hex string to byte array in c++.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261798/converting-a-hex-string-to-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: This makes little sense. You probably don't need any conversion. Please explain what your *real* problem is.

Answer (score 3):

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1681a5b03485e91a)**

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template <typename Out>
void hex2bin(std::string const& s, Out out) {
    assert(s.length() % 2 == 0);

    std::string extract;
    for (std::string::const_iterator pos = s.begin(); pos<s.end(); pos += 2)
    {
        extract.assign(pos, pos+2);
        *out++ = std::stoi(extract, nullptr, 16);
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;

    hex2bin("1023456789ABCD", back_inserter(v));

    for (auto byte : v)
        std::cout << std::hex << (int) byte << "\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
10
23
45
67
89
ab
cd
```

Answer (score -1):

when you say 'byte' it looks like you're meaning each character represented in hexidecimal.

in that case you could simply use `string.c_str()`, as this is just a c-style string (`char*`).

```
byte[2] = 0x45
```

is the same as

```
byte[2] = 69; //this is 0x45 in decimal
```

you could assign the output of `string.c_str()` to another `char*` if you wanted to store the array seperately.

Comment: `c_str()` doesn't convert anything. It certainly won't turn the example input into the example output.

Comment: @interjay: why not? const char* byte = abc.c_str();

Comment: @arashkordi Because the question is about converting a hexadecimal string into numbers. Look at the example given, not just at the title.