# Reading hex values from a String and storing them into an integer array in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, qt

I want to ask that how can I store hex values from a string into an integer array. 
e.g coverting

```
String sbox_str= "0x65, 0xea, 0xaf, 0x37, 0xff, 0x3b, 0xc2, 0xd0";
```

into

```
uint8_t sbox[8]={0x65, 0xea, 0xaf, 0x37, 0xff, 0x3b, 0xc2, 0xd0};
```

I will really appreciate if you guide me about how can i do the same thing in QT Creator.

Comment: What have you tried alraedy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Oh and please don't spam unrelated languages tags. If you program in C++ then use only that tag.

Comment: Use `strtok` to break up the string, then `strtol` to convert the values.

Comment: [Post what you're **fully** trying to do, not just a subproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). Qt provides some special functionalities that normal C++ doesn't naturally provide. Letting us know this can help us help you...

Comment: normal C++ way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17261798/103167

Answer (score 0):

Easy way using QString:

```
std::string sbox_str= "0x65, 0xea, 0xaf, 0x37, 0xff, 0x3b, 0xc2, 0xd0";
uint8_t sbox[8];

int i = 0;
for( const auto &item: QString(sbox_str.data()).split(", ")) {
    if(i == sizeof (sbox)) break; // do something
    sbox[i] = item.toInt(nullptr, 16);
    ++i;
}
```