# Hex_string to uint8_t msg[]

Tags: c++, arrays, hex, uint8t

I want convert the characters in hex string

```
"0b7c28c9b7290c98d7438e70b3d3f7c848fbd7d1dc194ff83f4f7cc9b1378e98"
```

to `uint8_t msg[]` and do not understand how to do it.

It seems simple, but have been unable to figure it out. I want to convert each character to a `uint8_t` hex value. For example if I have

```
string result = "0123456789abcdef";
```

How do I convert the string to:

```
uint8_t msg[] = "0123456789abcdef";
```

Comment: Convert to what? How exactly should the conversion be done? strtol is for a single number, but there exists no data type in C++ that can hold a large number like the one in your string. Should the conversion be on byte-per-byte basis or what? Please clarify.

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate of the following, where the answer is perhaps not the most efficient or C++-style: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261798/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array

Comment: The code seems to work ok: https://ideone.com/GpkqUT. What is your issue?

Comment: function accepts ...const uint8_t msg []... I only have a string hex symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a hex string to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261798/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: 1) I remember doing this with combination of `std::string::substr` (as you are doing), and `std::istringstream`, but your solution should work fine as well. 2) "_function accepts ...const uint8_t msg []... I only have a string hex symbol_" Which function? Yours accepts `const std::string&`.

Comment: Is it the [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I think you're overdoing this, `c_str` puls a cast to `const uint8_t*`. It's a one-liner, no separate function needed.

Comment: I do not understand what I am explaining wrong
there is a 
static void getHash function (const uint8_t msg [], size_t len, uint8_t hashResult [HASH_LEN]);
which takes an array of unsigned characters, I can't just pass a string there!

Comment: You can pass the contents of a string, the actual character array that the string wraps.

Comment: Your question doesn't really say what you're doing, what the actual problem is. You show us a solution that doesn't really solve your problem, so of course we attempt to guess what you want based on that information. You also show some unrelated equation that doesn't tell us anything. You don't tell us anything about the function you want to call, or what it *really* want (a *string* or an array of *bytes*, which are two different things).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude result.c_str():
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: @vbujym So add a cast. In this case it seems to be what is required.

Comment: And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @vbujym The fundamental question is does this function take character data, or integer data? I.e. how are the bytes you pass to the function going to be interpreted? You haven't actually said (maybe you don't know).

Comment: func: getHash(const uint8_t msg[], size_t len, uint8_t hashResult[HASH_LEN])
string result != uint8_t msg[] !!!!!!!!

Comment: @john maybe I still have to dance with big and little endian

Comment: But that doesn't help, especially in a comment. We need to know if the function expects a byte-array or a string. Right now it could be both, and even you seem to be wanting to pass a string to it. What documentation about the function do you have? And endianness is for multi-byte values, not for strings or single bytes.

Comment: And what does "32b - (64 + 1b) - 32b - 20b" have to do with it all?

Comment: @vbujym Funny, because `data` and `c_str` are the same.

Comment: @john
In the comment above, I gave the output of the compiler error
these methods are the same for strings and characters, but not for vector<uint8_t>

Comment: @johnny-mopp thanks! method data() helped me! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This func (thanks [Converting a hex string to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261798/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-byte-array) )

```
vector<uint8_t> HexToBytes(const string& hex) {
  vector<uint8_t> bytes;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
    string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
    uint8_t byte = (uint8_t) strtol(byteString.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
    bytes.push_back(byte);
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

using the above function we get the vector of bytes and call the method data()

I want to thank the community now everything is working correctly. Thanks for the comments, I was already desperate that I could not do such a simple thing.
Special thanks to @johnny-mopp

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - Updated to ready bytes not characters**

Rather than using `.substr()` and calling C `strtol` and casting to `uint8_t`, you can simply use an `istringstream` along with `std::setbase(16)` to read the bytes as `unsigned` values directly into your `vector<uint8_t> msg`. See [std::setbase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase).

For instance you can create an `istringstream` from your string containing the hex characters,  and then along with your vector of `uint8_t` and a temporary `unsigned` to read directly into before pushing back into your vector you could do, e.g.

```
    std::string result ("0123456789abcdef");    /* input hex string */
    std::string s2;                             /* string for 2-chars */
    std::istringstream ss (result);             /* stringstream of result */
    std::vector<uint8_t> msg;                   /* vector of uint8_t */

    while ((ss >> std::setw(2) >> s2)) {    /* read 2-char at a time */
        unsigned u;                         /* tmp unsigned value */
        std::istringstream ss2 (s2);        /* create 2-char stringstream */
        ss2 >> std::setbase(16) >> u;       /* convert hex to unsigned */
        msg.push_back((uint8_t)u);          /* add value as uint8_t */
    }
```

In that way, each 2 characters in `result` read using `std::setw(2)` are used to create a 2-character stringstream that is then converted a an `unsigned` value using `std::setbase(16)`. A complete example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    std::string result ("0123456789abcdef");    /* input hex string */
    std::string s2;                             /* string for 2-chars */
    std::istringstream ss (result);             /* stringstream of result */
    std::vector<uint8_t> msg;                   /* vector of uint8_t */

    while ((ss >> std::setw(2) >> s2)) {    /* read 2-char at a time */
        unsigned u;                         /* tmp unsigned value */
        std::istringstream ss2 (s2);        /* create 2-char stringstream */
        ss2 >> std::setbase(16) >> u;       /* convert hex to unsigned */
        msg.push_back((uint8_t)u);          /* add value as uint8_t */
    }

    std::cout << "string: " << result << "\nmsg: \n";
    for (auto& h : msg) /* for each element of msg, output hex value */
        std::cout << "\t" << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(2) 
                    << (uint32_t)h << '\n';;
}
```

(**note** the cast required in the output to explicitly tell `cout` to treat the `uint8_t` value as an `unsigned` value rather than a `uint8_t` value which defaults to an character type by default.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexstr2uint8_t
string: 0123456789abcdef
msg:
        01
        23
        45
        67
        89
        ab
        cd
        ef
```

(**note** there are 8 `uint8_t` ("byte") values stored this time instead of 16 character values)

It's just an alternative using the C++ iostream features which avoids the need to cast things around rather than calling `strtol` directly (which in your case should probably be `strtoul` to begin with).

**Manual Hex Conversion**

In your last comment you indicate that using iostream and stringstream for the conversion is slow. You can attempt to optimize a bit by eliminating the stringstream and using a `string::iterator` to step through the string manually converting each character and forming each `uint8_t` byte as you go (protecting against a final nibble or 1/2-byte), e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/* simple manual conversion of hexchar to value */
uint8_t c2hex (const char c)
{
    uint8_t u = 0;

    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        u = c - '0';
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f')
        u = c - 'W';
    else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
        u = c - '7';
    else
        std::cerr << "error: invalid hex char '" << c << "'\n";

    return u;
}

int main (void) {

    std::string s ("0123456789abcdef");
    std::vector<uint8_t> msg;

    for (std::string::iterator n = s.begin(); n != s.end(); n += 2) {
        uint8_t u = c2hex (*n);             /* save high-nibble */
        if (n + 1 != s.end())               /* if low-nibble available */
            u = (u << 4) | c2hex (n[1]);    /* shift high left 4 & or */
        msg.push_back(u);                   /* store byte in msg */
    }

    std::cout << "string: " << s << "\nmsg:\n";
    for (auto& h : msg)
        std::cout << "\t" << std::setfill('0') << std::hex 
                    << std::setw(2) << (unsigned)h << '\n';
}
```

(output is the same as above)

If you can guarantee there will always be an even number of characters in your string (bytes only and no 1/2-byte as the final-odd character), you can further optimize by removing the conditional and simply using:

```
        uint8_t u = c2hex (n[1]) | (c2hex (*n) << 4);
```

Make sure you are compiling with full optimization, e.g. `-O3` (or `-Ofast` gcc version >= 4.6) on gcc/clang and `/Ox` with VS.

Give that a try and compare performance, you can additionally dump the differing versions to assembly and see if there are any additional hints there.

Comment: it looks better, but unfortunately it’s not the same thing. I need this function for hashing, and if you use your option, you get a different result
my function gives the correct, I suppose it is in byte order, but I can not understand what is happening.
i use this simple library https://github.com/okdshin/PicoSHA2 metod picosha2::hash256_hex_string(hash, result)
string s = "0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352"
vector<uint8_t> hash = HexToBytes(s); //my function

result = 0b7c28c9b7290c98d7438e70b3d3f7c848fbd7d1dc194ff83f4f7cc9b1378e98 //it true

Comment: no, your function gives characters, and mine gives bytes, that’s all the difference.
I just understand that I do not understand anything at all

Comment: OK, now I understand. It was confusing because every "byte", (e.g. `"1f"` is two "nibbles" or two ASCII characters). It is just as easy to change it to read bytes and not characters. All you do is change `std::setw(1)` to `std::setw(2)`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You could help me with this, because I’m definitely already completely confused.I will be very grateful and grateful! setw(2) ? no, it's simple not work !

Comment: Sure, I just edited my answer. Each hex digit `0, 1, 2, 3 ... c, d, e, f` is a value which can be represented by 4-bits (called a "nibble"). There are 2-nibbles per byte. However, everything you type is a `character`, so the ASCII characters `0, 1, 2, 3 ... c, d, e, f` are represented by 7-bit values ranging from `32 - 126`. To store as `uint8_t` you must convert each ASCII character byte into a hex digit. Then since you can fit two hex-digits in every byte, you see each hex byte as `01, 23, .. ef`. (which does make it confusing) See [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the help and time spent, this function works correctly! but unfortunately it is not very fast. But thank you! In general, I am amazed that in C ++ there is no such function in the standard library. Working with bytes is the basis of the basics. Even in python there is a function bytes.fromhex()...

Comment: If you want it fast, write it in C. It's actually easier and will be much faster.

Comment: @vbujym - see if the final addition with manual conversion doesn't speed things up a bit. Make sure you are compiling with full optimization, e.g. `-O3` (or `-Ofast`) on gcc/clang and `/Ox` with VS.