# Converting std::string of hexadecimal to std::array<T, 6>

Tags: c++

A 12 byte string which represents 6 hexadecimal values, needs to be converted to an `std:array<uint8_t,6>`. I am getting erroneous results from the hexadecimal conversions. I re-purposed some of the code over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606613/3174123) for the Hex conversions from a string. Thank you for your time

**Code**

```
std::vector<std::array<uint8_t,6> > tracker =
  {
    { 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66 },
    { 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99 }
  };

std::array<uint8_t, 6> singular= { 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22 };

void setMac() {
  Serial.println("MAC TEST 1");
  std::string macInput = "121212121212";
  macTrans(macInput);

  tracker.push_back(singular);
  for (const auto& target : tracker)
  {
    printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", target[0], target[1], target[2], target[3], target[4], target[5]);
  }
}

void macTrans(std::string mac){
    singular = HexToBytes(mac);
}

std::array<uint8_t,6> HexToBytes(const std::string& hex) {
  std::array<uint8_t,6> bytes;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length() && i < 12; i += 2) {
    std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
    uint8_t byte = (unsigned char) strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    if (i==0)
      bytes[0] = byte;
    else
      bytes[i-1] = byte;
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
MAC TEST 1

66:66:66:66:66:66
99:99:99:99:99:99
12:12:30:12:fe:12
```

**Expected Output:**

```
MAC TEST 1

66:66:66:66:66:66
99:99:99:99:99:99
12:12:12:12:12:12
```

Comment: Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: Why does `macTrans` use a global variable rather than just returning the value?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because this is an example snippet and the actual production code is embedded

Comment: Considering changing the title of the OP to: "Posting to SO at 2am: A Cautionary Tale"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `HexToBytes`, you're writing outside the array, and that has undefined behaviour.
(You are writing to positions 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9.)

When you "repurposed" the code you found, you should have used division by two instead of subtraction by one.

Replace

```
if (i==0)
  bytes[0] = byte;
else
  bytes[i-1] = byte;
```

with

```
  bytes[i/2] = byte;
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this post when I was burnt out of my mind and I appreciate the (albeit obvious) answer you posited here.