# C++ std::copy in forward method is not working

Tags: c++, iterator, visual-studio-2019

Visual study 2013 An error occurred after migrating the developing project to 2019,

Perhaps operator= is no longer supported

It's my code, the source that concatenates the list of std::list to ';'

main.cpp

```
std::list<string> filters;
...
...

stringstream ss;
std::copy(filters.begin(), filters.end(), FilterIterator<string>(ss));
```

FilterIterator.h

```
#include <ostream> 
#include <iterator> 

template <class T>

class FilterIterator :
    public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> *os;
    char const delimiter;
    bool first_elem;
public:
    //typedef TCHAR char_type;
    //typedef traits traits_type;
    typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> ostream_type;

    FilterIterator(ostream_type& s)
        : os(&s), delimiter(_T(';')), first_elem(true)
    {}
    FilterIterator<T>& operator=(T const &item)
    {
        if (!first_elem && delimiter != 0)
            *os << delimiter;
        *os << item;
        first_elem = false;
        return *this;
    }
    FilterIterator<T> &operator*() {
        return *this;
    }
    FilterIterator<T> &operator++() {
        return *this;
    }
    FilterIterator<T> &operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

> Error C2280   'FilterIterator
> &FilterIterator::operator =(const FilterIterator
> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function   LogRotate   C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility  1378

Comment: I'm Korean, and I'm still not good at using stackoverflow
I'm not good at English, and if there's anything I need to secure, please let me know

Comment: The perfect English is not required, just post the complete error messages as a code without reductions.

Comment: @273K I understand. I'm sorry.
The reason why I didn't upload the entire error message is because the compiler is the Korean version, so I only uploaded the error code.
I'll check and upload it.

Comment: C2280: 'FilterIterator<tstring> &FilterIterator<tstring>::operator =(const FilterIterator<tstring> &)' attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: @JaMiT I'll correct the question now.

Comment: The error is clear, you haven't implemented the assignment operator.

Comment: Your custom iterator is totally wrong. Read e.g [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054856/4165552) and correct your iterator interfaces.

Comment: Example I referenced (vs120 no problem) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355864/stdostream-iterator-prevent-last-item-from-using-the-delimiter)

Comment: You can't have a `const` member in a class that needs to be assignable. `const` members are rarely a good idea

Comment: @AlanBirtles Wow;;; Thank You :)