# lambda function capture and modify own reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Sometimes there is a need to execute a particular function once and than switch to another implementation.

For example, I am really annoyed by the stream output iterator which prints delimiter after the item being printed in conjunction with the copy algorithm:

```
> 1,2,3,4,
         ^---- this is what happens in that case
```

The question isn't about nicely printing items, but more about properly concatenating them.

For example Python produces a correct result using `string.join` function:

```
','.join((1,2,3,4))
> 1,2,3,4
```

I also want to avoid `if/else` statement, because we only need once to make the switch after the first execution. So what I came up with, is:

```
std::function<char const*()> get_delim;

get_delim = [&get_delim]()
{
  get_delim = [](){ return ","; };
  return "";
};

for(auto b : some_byte_range)
  std::cout << get_delim() << b;
```

**Note**: `b` is just a byte in my case, that's why I did not use `auto const&`.

Now the questions:

- Is there a way to get rid of the prior `std::function<char const*()>` declaration and somehow declare `get_delim` with `auto` which effectively involves self-capturing of lambda?
- Is there may be another more expressive (like in Python) way to do that kind of `join`?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c) concerning comma-separated output has some interesting ideas

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use `auto` because lambda types are unique (you won't be able to assign a different lambda to such variable). But why lambdas? It's a nice trickery, but you could as well just write a simple function which constructs needed string using a plain loop with an if or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, all you need is:

```
auto get_delim = [c=char(0)]() mutable {
    char cur = c;
    c = ',';
    return cur;
};
```

or even:

```
auto get_delim = [c=char(0)]() mutable { return std::exchange(c, ','); }
```

Or use `""` and `","` if you prefer, should be easy to see how to adjust this to suit your needs.

---

As far as library goes, there is a [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner).

Comment: But that would execute std::exchange every time `get_delim` is called?

Comment: @ovanes Assigning a char is pretty cheap.

Comment: Well, I know that... :) I am just trying to understand what is involved...

Comment: But I like your solution :) It is very elegant (the second proposal with one-liner). I know about ostream_joiner, but it's not part of the standard lib right now :(

Comment: or `auto get_delim = [first=true]() mutable { return first ? first = false, "" : ","; }` though the conditional branch is probably just as expensive as the swap.