# C++ print element sum

Tags: c++, loops, io, iterator

It's my first time with C++.

i searched other question, but i couldn't solve my problem :(

I just want to print all of element of list and print sum.

But, i got some problem of char "+"

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    list<int> square;
    int n, m;
    cout << "Please enter tow positive integers between M and N -> ";
    cin >> m >> n;
    while (m>=n) {
        cout << "Please try agrin" << endl;
        cin >> m >> n;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i=i+1) {
        /*cout << i << endl;*/
        if (i*i >= m && i*i <= n) {
            square.push_back(i*i);
            count=count+1;
            sum = sum + (i*i); 
            //cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
    for (list<int>::iterator i = square.begin(); i != square.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << "+";
    cout << "=" << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

I got output like below.

```
16+25+36+49+64+81+100+=371
```

but i wanna get like below.

```
16+25+36+49+64+81+100=371
```

that has no "+" char at last element.

But i don't know how to do.

Is there any idea for this?

Comment: Iterate to the back of your list and print the last element after the loop.

Comment: @George Your point is valid. It seems however to be improveable by rephrasing with more details. Consider making an answer to have more formatting features available.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c) you can find a lot of different solution to your problem

Answer (score 3):

Check in every iteration if you are *not* printing the last element with ([`std::prev`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/)), and then print the plus sign.

Like this:

```
for (list<int>::iterator i = square.begin(); i != square.end(); ++i) {
    cout << *i; if(i != std::prev(square.end())) cout << "+";
}
```

---

PS: In order to avoid checking the iterator twice in every iteration, you would need to print with the plus sign appended until the prelast element and then print the last element *outside* the loop without the plus sign.

Example:

```
for (list<int>::iterator i = square.begin(); i != std::prev(square.end()); ++i)
    cout << *i << "+";
cout << *std::prev(square.end());
cout << "=" << sum;
```

Comment: not the most efficient though, because it checks the iterator twice each time.

Comment: @ROX I agree, and in fact this was my initial approach, but I was downvotes, thus changed course. I now injected it back to my answer, what to you say?

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking, given the = sign means there was always going to be a special case at the end of the loop anyway ( although I suppose one could put that in the loop too ). don't know why it attracted downvotes - no comments to explain that.

Comment: by the way typo outise -> outside (I couldn't just correct it for you due to stupid rule about minimum number of characters in edit)

Answer (score 1):

Using a [ostream_joiner](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner) one can solve your problem elegantly:

```
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(cbegin(square), cend(square),
          std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, "+"));
std::cout << "=" << sum;
```

It depends on your compiler whether `ostream_joiner` is already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the numbers while iterating and print the '+' only between the elements:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i=i+1) {
    if (i*i >= m && i*i <= n) {
        if (count) // If we already printed a number then include also a plus sign
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << (i*i);
        square.push_back(i*i);
        count=count+1;
        sum = sum + (i*i); 
    }
}

cout << "=" << sum;
```

Or if yo dont want to mix the output code with the other yo can modify only the print loop:

```
for (list<int>::iterator i = square.begin(); i != square.end(); ++i)
{
    if (i != square.begin()) 
    {
        cout <<"+"; 
    }
    cout << *i;
}
```