# How to access the position of an object within a vector when using an iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm currently doing this:

```
for (std::vector<myClass>::const_iterator i = myVec.begin(); i != myVec.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

As it is the recommended way to output all the members of a vector. The problem is that this means that all of my members of this vector get output on a singular line. I want to have it so that I instead output 5 on each line, so that I don't have to scroll too long.  If I didn't use an iterator, so my `i` was just an `int`, I could just say `if (i%5 == 0)` then `cout << endl` but because it is an iterator, I am confused. I tried varying ways of saying what I want to do, but I can't find an answer... Is this possible with an iterator, or should I just use an int instead..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, there are a lot of possibilities to achieve this. But to answer your initial question:

```
for (std::vector<myClass>::const_iterator i = myVec.begin(); i != myVec.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";

    size_t index = i - myVec.begin();
    if (index % 5 == 0) {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This prints the value at the iterator position and the index in the vector. You calculate the difference between the `begin()` of the vector and the current iterator position, which is the index.

While it is possible to do this, I wouldn't recommend it because you have an additional subtraction in every iteration. This is generally not a situation where iterators are very useful, as you've seen for yourself.

If you have access to a sufficiently modern C++ compiler (which I guess you do), you can use the very elegant *range-based for-loops*:

```
for (myClass& obj : myVec) {
    std::cout << obj;
}
```

This "extracts" references to the objects in your vector. Of course, now you're even farther away from the index position because you can't use the iterator-subtraction trick. To solve your problem of keeping an index you can simply keep a separate index counter:

```
int i = 0;
for (myClass& obj : myVec) {
    std::cout << obj << ", ";
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Or even use the very new C++20 feature of inline-initialized variables (I don't remember the official name for these):

```
for (int i = 0; myClass& obj : myVec) {
    std::cout << obj << ", ";
    if (i++ % 5 == 0) {
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Or you can just use the classical `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) ...`, though this isn't as clear as the range-based for-loop version. With the range-based for-loop it's possible to instantly see that something is done with all objects in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with iterators:

```
for (std::vector<myClass>::const_iterator i = myVec.begin(); i != myVec.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ", ";
    if (i != myVec.begin() && std::distance(myVec.begin(), i) % 5 == 0)
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

In this case, a counting loop would work as well:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < myVec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << myVec[i] << ", ";
    if (i && i % 5 == 0)
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You could write this with a range-for loop as well:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto &elem : myVec) {
    std::cout << elem << ", ";
    if (++i % 5 == 0)
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you use the range-v3 library, you could do:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
for (auto line : myVec | rs::views::chunk(5)) {
    rs::copy(line, rs::ostream_iterator<myClass>(std::cout, ",");
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

or instead:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;
for (auto [i, line] : rv::enumerate(myVec)) {
    std::cout << elem << ", ";
    if (i && i % 5 == 0)
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do be aware that `std::distance(myVec.begin(), i) % 5 == 0` and `if (i % 5 == 0)` will be true when `i` is at the 1st element, thus outputting an undesirable line break after the 1st comma.

Comment: When `i` is an iterator, `if (i &&` should be `if (i != begin() &&` instead

Answer (score 3):

Add `int pos = i-myVec.begin()`. Then you can use `if (pos%5 == 0)` as you wanted.

Comment: A bit short but in my opinion this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, you might do:

```
for (int counter = 0; auto&& e : myVec) {
    std::cout << e << ", ";
    if (++counter == 5) {
        counter = 0;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Before,

```
int counter = 0;
for (auto&& e : myVec) {
    std::cout << e << ", ";
    if (++counter == 5) {
        counter = 0;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, this is still a poor solution. It depends on someone manually incrementing the variable, and prone to all issues. Ideally we would have a python-style `enumerate`, which would allow for control variable and iterator to be accessible.

Comment: @SergeyA I like that idea, decided to add it to my answer :)

Comment: @cigien and I posted a home-brew solution for the good measure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a different variable to use it for counting:

```
// example vector
vector<int> myVec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
int c = 0;

for (auto i = myVec.begin(); i != myVec.end(); i++) {
    // incrementing the counter and verifying if it gives 0 as the remainder
    if (c++ % 5 == 0)
        cout << endl;

    std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

You'll then get:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,        // 5 values
6, 7, 8, 9, 10,       // 5 values
11, 12, 13, 14, 15,   // 5 values
```

**Note:** You may use `auto` keyword to reduce such long declaration:

```
std::vector<myClass>::const_iterator i = myVec.begin();
// better:
auto i = myVec.begin();
```

Comment: Note that you are outputting a line break before the 1st element is output.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here is a sample code which allows you to access to both index and value through range-for loop. This has limited value, but shows general approach (RangesTS has this built-in):

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class UnderlyingIterator>
struct IndexingIterator {
    using ValueType = std::pair<long long int, const typename UnderlyingIterator::value_type&>;
    IndexingIterator(const UnderlyingIterator it) : underlyingIterator(it) { }

    IndexingIterator& operator++() {
        ++underlyingIterator;
        ++ix;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator != (const IndexingIterator& rhs) const {
        return underlyingIterator != rhs.underlyingIterator;
    }

    ValueType operator*() const {
        return ValueType{ix, *underlyingIterator};
    }

    long long int index() const { return ix; }

private:
    UnderlyingIterator underlyingIterator;

    long long int ix = 0;
};

template<class Container>
struct Enumeratable {
    using Iterator = typename Container::const_iterator;
    using Indexing = IndexingIterator<Iterator>;

    Enumeratable(const Container& container) : b{container.begin()}, e{container.end()} {}

    Indexing begin() const { return b; }
    Indexing end() const { return e; }

private:
    Indexing b;
    Indexing e;
};

template<class Container>
auto enumerate(const Container& container) {
     return Enumeratable<Container>{container};  
}

void testDriver(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    for (const auto& [index, value]: enumerate(vec)) {
         std::cout << index << ": " << value << "\n";
    }
 }

 int main() {
     std::vector<int> vec{10, 34, 122, 12};

     testDriver(vec);
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!myVec.empty())
{
    auto iter = myVec.begin(), end = myVec.end();
    size_t count = 0;
    do {
        std::cout << *iter++;
        if (iter == end) break;
        std::cout << ", ";
        if ((++count % 5) == 0)
            std::cout << '\n';
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write a custom iterator that mimics [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) (or better, [`infix_iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c/3497021#3497021)), injecting additional line breaks into the output when needed, eg:

```
#include <ostream> 
#include <iterator> 

template <class T, 
          class charT = char, 
          class traits = std::char_traits<charT> > 
class my_infix_ostream_iterator : 
    public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void> 
{ 
    std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> *os;
    charT const* delimiter;
    size_t counter, numPerLine;

public: 
    typedef charT char_type; 
    typedef traits traits_type; 
    typedef std::basic_ostream<charT,traits> ostream_type; 

    my_infix_ostream_iterator(ostream_type& s, size_t numPerLine = 0, charT const *d = 0) 
        : os(&s), delimiter(d), numPerLine(numPerLine), counter(0)
    {} 

    my_infix_ostream_iterator& operator=(T const &item)
    { 
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            if (delimiter)
                *os << delimiter; 
            if ((numPerLine > 0) && ((counter % numPerLine) == 0))
                *os << os->widen('\n');
        }
        *os << item;
        ++counter;
        return *this;
    }

    my_infix_ostream_iterator& operator*() { 
        return *this;
    }

    my_infix_ostream_iterator& operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    my_infix_ostream_iterator& operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
my_infix_ostream_iterator<myClass> iter(std::cout, 5, ", ");
for (const auto &elem : myVec) {
    *iter++ = elem;
}
```

or:

```
std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
    my_infix_ostream_iterator<myClass>(std::cout, 5, ", ")
);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/AZwtV4)