# How to make a spaced line of strings from a vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, range-based-loop

I want to make a line like this `hello my name sounds very fancy` from a vector of these words (`std::vector<std::string> myvector = {"hello", "my", "name", "sounds", "very", "fancy"}`).

What is the most efficient way to perform such convertion without inserting redundant spaces, as would happen if I used

```
for (auto element : v) {
    std::cout << word_from_vector << ' ';
}
```

?

Comment: Define _efficient_. What's wrong with your loop?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As I pointed out, when I use "for element loop", there is an extra space at the end, and I was wondering how I could substitube this loop and get rid of the space.

Comment: Why not just `for( const auto& word_from_vector) { std::cout << word_from_vector << " "; }` ?

Comment: Same as already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/how-can-i-print-a-list-of-elements-separated-by-commas @SharkyMonkey

Comment: @SharkyMonkey you should [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: `auto sep = ""; for (auto&& x : v) { cout << exchange(sep, " ") << x; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++ 20 then you can write the range-based for loop the following way to eliminate the trailing space

```
for ( bool next = false; const auto &element : myvector ) 
{
    if ( next )
    {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        next = true;
    }
    std::cout << element;
}
```

Otherwise you could use the ordinary for loop like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < myvector.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( i != 0 ) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << myvector[i]
}
```