# Is it safe to output a NULL char to std::cout?

Tags: c++, stdout, iostream, null-character, non-printing-characters

Even though it is a very little problem, but every time when I need to print out some data in a loop, how to arrange the separating char always annoys me.

For example:

```
std::set<int> my_data { 1, 2, 3 };
bool is_first { true };
std::cout << '{';
for( auto i : my_data ) {
    if( is_first )
        std::cout << i;
    else
        std::cout << ',' << i;
    is_first = false;
}
std::cout << '}';
```

Or:

```
std::set<int> my_data { 1, 2, 3 };
size_t cnt { 0 };
cout << '{';
for( auto i : my_data )
    if( ++cnt == my_data.size() )
        std::cout << i;
    else
        std::cout << i << ',';
std::cout << '}';
```

You can see in my codes, in order to insert a separating char at correct places, I used 4~5 lines in the loop while the real job is merely `std::cout << i;`!

So, I often do it like this:

```
std::set<int> my_data { 1, 2, 3 };
char sep { '\0' };
cout << '{';
for( auto i : my_data ) {
    std::cout << sep << i;
    sep = ',';
}
std::cout << '}';
```

Is it safe to output a NULL ('\0') char to std::cout? I'm using this method mainly in my daemon programs, so in this way they mainly prints some log text to std::cout/std::cerr, or other text files in a Linux filesystem.

The result files(log file), mainly are read by some cli tools such as `more/less/tail/head`.

In this way, will I encounter any crash? In other words, would the NULL char be ignored silently by the file system/terminal/stdout/...?

Comment: Yes, it is safe assuming by safe you mean well-formed.

Comment: Tip: `const char* sep = "";` and `sep = ",";` make your question go away for very little extra overhead...

Comment: *"ignored silently by fs/terminal/stdout/"* -- Is "fs" supposed to mean "file system"?

Comment: It won't be *ignored* as such. Some terminals display nothing, some might display an "unprintable" symbol, a file will just contain it and whether you see it depends on what you use to look at it.

Comment: Related (not about outputting `\0`, but about outputting comma-separated lists): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/how-can-i-print-a-list-of-elements-separated-by-commas

Comment: @JaMiT  Yes, here "fs" is meaning "filesystem".  Thanks for sharing your method, I think it is very nice also!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would the NULL char be ignored silently by fs/terminal/stdout/...?

**File system:**
No, the null character will not be ignored. It would get saved in the file just like every other character. Whether or not this will mess up your cli tools depends on the tools, and potentially on how you use them.

**Terminal:**
Depends on the terminal. The ones I've sent null characters to have ignored the character, but others are free to display it however they want. (A space or some variant on a question mark are two common approaches for non-printable characters.)

**stdout:**
No, the null character will not be ignored. The null character will be passed on to the destination (which is often the terminal, but could be redirected to a file).

**In summary,** `std::cout << '\0';` is likely to have no visible effect, but your mileage may vary.

***Caveat,** esp. for future readers: don't confuse `'\0'` with `"\0"`. Streaming the former sends a null character through `std::cout`, while streaming the latter sends no characters, the same as if it was the empty string. On a related note, if you change the definition of `sep` to `const char* sep = "";` and the later assignment to `sep = ",";`, you can get the desired formatting and avoid streaming the null character.*

Comment: I would suggest you also mention (and explain) the tip you gave in comments below the question.  Although it doesn't address the question *as asked*, it does provide a solution to the problem the OP appears *actually* trying to solve.

Comment: also, `std::string` containing `/0` in middle would be still printed in full `int main() { std::string s{"Hello, World!"}; s[5] = '\0'; std::cout << s << std::endl; }`. Only streaming or assigning char literals or arrays would be stopped at null characer.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Right. That's why I stuck to string literals (with no suffix), avoiding `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safely to output a NULL char to std::cout?

Yes, it is safe assuming by safe you mean well-formed.

> In this way, will I encounter any crash?

No, a well-formed program has a well-defined behavior.