# C++ do while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I have a vector holding 10 items (all of the same class for simplicity call it 'a'). What I want to do is to check that 'A' isn't either a) hiding the walls or b) hiding another 'A'. I have a collisions function that does this.

The idea is simply to have this looping class go though and move 'A' to the next position, if that potion is causing a collision then it needs to give itself a new random position on the screen. Because the screen is small, there is a good chance that the element will be put onto of another one (or on top of the wall etc).  The logic of the code works well in my head - but debugging the code the object just gets stuck in the loop, and stay in the same position. 'A' is supposed to move about the screen, but it stays still!

When I comment out the Do while loop, and move the 'MoveObject()' Function up the code works perfectly the 'A's are moving about the screen. It is just when I try and add the extra functionality to it is when it doesn't work.

```
    void Board::Loop(void){


        //Display the postion of that Element. 
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){


            do {

                if (checkCollisions(i)==true){
                moveObject(i); 
                }
                else{
                    objects[i]->ResetPostion();

                }

            }
            while (checkCollisions(i) == false);
            objects[i]->SetPosition(objects[i]->getXDir(),objects[i]->getYDir());
        }

}
```

The class below is the collision detection. This I will expand later.

```
    bool Board::checkCollisions(int index){

    char boundry = map[objects[index]->getXDir()][objects[index]->getYDir()];

    //There has been no collisions - therefore don't change anything 
    if(boundry == SYMBOL_EMPTY){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;

    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I will buy you a virtual beer :-)

Thanks

Edit:

ResetPostion -> this will give the element A a random position on the screen
moveObject -> this will look at the direction of the object and adjust the x and Y cord's appropriately.

Comment: +1 for the virtual beer.

Comment: doesn't `->SetPosition()` pretty much do the same thing as `moveObject()`?  Perhaps remove one or the other from the code sample to avoid confusion?  Also, why the infinite `while()**;**`? and even without the semicolon, why move `i` twice in one loop?

Comment: The 10 elements are in an array. The first index starts from 0 not from 1, doesn't it? Anyway what ResetPosition does? Nothing?

Comment: Good point. Take your point on board. I will merge the two into one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need:

```
do { ...
... } while (checkCollisions(i));
```

Also, if you have 10 elements, then `i = 0; i < 10; i++`

And btw. don't write `if (something == true)`, simply `if (something)` or `if (!something)`

Comment: @gcvt You've inverted the while condition, `while (!checkCollisions(i));` would be the same as the original code.

Comment: I did that on purpose, since he suggested his code doesn't work, I assumed he wants to loop while there is a collision...

Comment: Yup - while there is a collision, reset the postion of that element and test again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
```

is wrong because that's a loop for eleven items, use

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
```

instead.

You don't define what 'doesn't work' means, so that's all the help I can give for now.

Comment: When I run the code, the objects are displayed on screen, and then once it goes through the collision detection the screen remains blank. VERY odd.. I have narrowed it down to this code, as when I remove it from Main It works but without coliding. Added another paragraph! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop to me. Are you sure your do while loop terminates?

Comment: yes the loop goes through all 10, I have just put a break point in and tracked the value of (i)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion here over basic language structure and logic flow.  Writing a few very simple test apps that exercise different language features will probably help you a lot.  (So will a step-thru debugger, if you have one)

`do/while()` is a fairly advanced feature that some people spend whole careers never using, see: [do...while vs while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347001/do-while-vs-while)

I recommend getting a solid foundation with `while` and `if/else` before even using `for`.  Your first look at `do` should be when you've just finished a `while` or `for` loop and realize you could save a mountain of duplicate initialization code if you just changed the order of execution a bit.  (Personally I don't even use `do` for that any more, I just use an iterator with `while(true)/break` since it lets me pre **and** post code all within a single loop)

I think this simplifies what you're trying to accomplish:

```
void Board::Loop(void) {
    //Display the postion of that Element. 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        while(IsGoingToCollide(i))  //check is first, do while doesn't make sense
            objects[i]->ResetPosition();
        moveObject(i);   //same as ->SetPosition(XDir, YDir)?
                         //either explain difference or remove one or the other
    }
}
```

This function name seems ambiguous to me:

```
bool Board::checkCollisions(int index) {
```

I'd recommend changing it to:

```
// returns true if moving to next position (based on inertia) will 
// cause overlap with any other object's or structure's current location
bool Board::IsGoingToCollide(int index) {
```

In contrast `checkCollisions()` could also mean:

```
// returns true if there is no overlap between this object's
// current location and any other object's or structure's current location
bool Board::DidntCollide(int index) {
```

Final note: Double check that `->ResetPosition()` puts things **inside** the boundaries.