# How to use while loop for multiple statements inside?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
main()    

{   
    int em;
    char name,add;

    cout<<"\n enter number of employees : ";
    cin>>em;
    // here we took an input by the name employee...

    while(em<=9)      //using while loop
```

Employee number is stored in `em` and put in the loop...
In order to put multiple responses I put two input keywords in code block... but it's not working properly.

```
    {
        cout<<"\n enter name: ";      //code block 
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"\n enter address : ";
        cin>>add;

        em=em+1;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the best option is to read an introductory level c++ book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [do...while vs while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347001/do-while-vs-while)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your declaration of `char name,add;` It should be either something like `char name[100],add[100];` or (in more modern, safer C++) `std::string name,add;`. In the latter case you also need to `#include <string>`.