# Beginner problem with printf and scanf in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have a problem with `scanf()` and `printf()` function in a snippet of code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    while (c >= 2) {
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        printf ("%d\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect to happen, and happens in my brother's Code::Block, is for the program to wait for input from `stdin` and then print to `stdout` the results, one per line, until it reaches the highest common divisor.

However, when I type it in `vi` and then compile it with `gcc` and run the program from my terminal, the program correctly takes the input but exit without returning anything to `stdout`.

If I comment out the `scanf()` line and hardcode any number to `a` and `b` variables, everything works as expected.

I'm trying to learn C and I've read basic documentation on the functions, but I can't help to understand this kind of behaviour.
I've tried to put a `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` before declaring variables but nothing changed.

Can somebody give me a clue?

Comment: `c` is unitialized

Comment: The compiler or the OS is effectively making `c` to be zero. If it isn't, then every so often when you execute it, it might print something on stdout. It's undefined behavior, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your `scanf` and `printf` calls but, as others have mentioned, one *obvious* problem is that you are testing the value of an uninitialised variable (`c`).

Maybe, what you want is a `do { ... } while (...);` loop, rather than a simple `while` loop.

The following code will **guarantee** to execute the loop **at least once** and then, at the **end** of each loop, check whether or not to repeat it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);
    do {
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        printf ("%d\n", c);
    } while (c >= 2);
    return 0;
}
```

(Alternatively, initialise `c` with a value that is `>= 2`, i.e. use the declaration: `int c = 3;`.)

For further discussion of the `do .. while` loop, see here: ['do...while' vs. 'while'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3347001/10871073)

Comment: There is something wrong with the `scanf()`, although not the cause of the problem. The OP should check the return value to detect invalid input and avoid proceeding if `a` or `b` were not read properly.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes I can't/won't argue with that! :)