# The do-while statement

Tags: javascript, do-while

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is a do-while appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035229/when-is-a-do-while-appropriate)

Would someone mind telling me what the difference between these two statements are and when one should be used over the other?

```
var counterOne = -1;

do {
    counterOne++;
    document.write(counterOne);
} while(counterOne < 10);
```

**Or:**

```
var counterTwo = -1;

while(counterTwo < 10) {
    counterTwo++;
    document.write(counterTwo);
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/g6JS4/

At this moment in time I don't see the point of the `do` statement if it can just be done without specifying it inside the `while` statement.

Comment: @lwburk: I'm not asking about other loops (`for`, `switch`, `if`). I'm wondering what the difference between `while` and `do-while` is.

Comment: Non sequitur. That's exactly what that question was about.

Comment: Maybe you'd prefer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347001/do-while-vs-while or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390605/while-vs-do-while or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094972/when-should-i-use-do-while-instead-of-while-loops or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/test-loops-at-the-top-or-bottom-while-vs-do-while or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994905/is-there-ever-a-need-for-a-do-while-loop

Comment: This question could still be usefully considered a non-duplicate because it is specifically scoped to JavaScript. There may be certain gotchas or discouragements for its usage not relevant to other languages. However, at least at this time, there appear to be none of those.

Comment: Whoever decided that this question is a duplicate may not have read the whole question. The other question just asks when you would use `do … while`, not how it differs from `while …`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do / While VS While is a matter of when the condition is checked.

A while loop checks the condition, then executes the loop. A Do/While executes the loop and then checks the conditions.

For example, if the `counterTwo` variable was 10 or greater, then do/while loop would execute once, while your normal while loop would not execute the loop.

Answer (score 11):

The `do-while` is guaranteed to run at least once. While the `while` loop may not run at all.

Answer (score 2):

`do while` checks the conditional after the block is run. `while` checks the conditional before it is run. This is usually used in situations where the code is always run at least once.

Answer (score 1):

The do statement normally ensures your code gets executed at least once (expression evaluated at the end), whilst while evaluates at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you wanted to process the block inside the loop at least once, regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

if you would get the counterTwo value as a return value of another function, you would safe in the first case an if statement.

e.g.

```
var counterTwo = something.length; 

while(counterTwo > 0) {
    counterTwo--;
    document.write(something.get(counterTwo));
}
```

or

```
var counterTwo = something.length; 

if(counterTwo < 0) return;

do
{
        counterTwo--;
    document.write(something.get(counterTwo));
} while(counterTwo > 0);
```

the first case is useful, if you process the data in an existing array.
the second case is useful, if you "gather" the data:

```
do
{
     a = getdata();
     list.push(a);
} while(a != "i'm the last item");
```