# Do While or while?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to make my program run only while the user enters Y or y but it only runs once, and even if it isn't Y or y. Input will either be Y, y, N or n

```
printf("Welcome to the Jumble Puzzle Solver!\n\n");
printf("Would you like to enter a jumbled word?\n");
scanf("%s", &answer);


    do{

    printf("What word would you like scored?\n");
    scanf("%s", &letters);

    strcpy(changeletters, letters);

    recursivepermute(letters, changeletters, checkword, k, dictionary ,max, min);

    printf("Would you like to enter a jumbled word?\n");
    scanf("%s", &answer);

    }while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
```

Comment: What type is `answer`? Also, the homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test loops at the top or bottom? (while vs. do while)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224059/test-loops-at-the-top-or-bottom-while-vs-do-while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do { } while()` causes the body to always be executed *at least once*.  If you want the condition checked first, just use while:

```
// If answer is:
// char answer;

scanf("%c", &answer);
while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
{
     printf("What word would you like scored?\n");
    // ...

    scanf("%c", &answer);
}
```

You also need to use `scanf("%c"` if `answer` is a `char`.  The `%s` is to scan a string of characters (ie: `char[20]`), and would need to be checked differently, using a method like [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) or similar.

Comment: Ok the do while explanation makes a lot of sense. I changed it t %c and made the while loop like this, but even if I enter Y or y it still ends the program.

Comment: @Ryan Check what you're getting in `answer` in a debugger.  Is it 'Y' or 'y'?  How is `answer` declared?

Comment: Ah figured out my problem. Still had it declared as char answer[2] instead of just char answer. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @Ryan With a string, you could use `strcmp` to do the check instead of checking against a single character.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the user to play the game once and then be asked about playing again then the use of `do-while` loop is more appropriate. But if you want to give the user the option Not to play the game at all then use the `while` loop

Comment: Thank you that explains a lot