# C language while used after do

Tags: c, loops, cs50

From Harvard's CS50 course

basically he has a function

where he says

```
do {
    int n = get_int("Positive number")
}
while ;
```

He wants the program to repeat positive number until the user inputs a positive number. Why is the while loop on the bottom of his do function?

Comment: because it's a do() while loop!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While vs. Do While](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224059/364696)

Comment: You need an expression after `while`.

Comment: That's not real code. The parenthesized condition after the `while` keyword is mandatory.

Comment: If you put the test at the top, you'll check the number before the user enters it. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Barmar: I realized after I marked it that the question I suggested was merged with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224059/364696), so no actual answers are at the direct link. Could you add the direct linked to the merged question to the set of duplicates to save some clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Because he want to get a number from the user then if it was positive, he will ask for another number, do while loops execute the code within the first time without any checking, then it gets repeted if the condition was true, whereas while loop will check for the condition first, and it will execute the cod only if condition was true